# Remove HTML tags from a String

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

Is there a good way to remove HTML from a Java string? A simple regex like

```js
replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "")
```

will work, but some things like `&amp;` won't be converted correctly and non-HTML between the two angle brackets will be removed (i.e. the `.*?` in the regex will disappear).

Comment: use this with following guide : compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/5733853

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838532/363573

Answer (score 656, accepted):

Use a HTML parser instead of regex. This is dead simple with [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org).

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Jsoup also [supports](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/safelist-sanitizer) removing HTML tags against a customizable whitelist, which is very useful if you want to allow only e.g. `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>`.

#### See also:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
- [What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)
- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: Jsoup is nice, but I encountered some drawbacks with it. I use it to get rid of XSS, so basically I expect a plain text input, but some evil person could try to send me some HTML. Using Jsoup, I can remove all HTML but, unfortunately it also shrinks many spaces to one and removes link breaks (\n characters)

Comment: @Ridcully: for that you'd like to use [`Jsoup#clean()`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) instead.

Comment: using clean() will still cause extra spaces and \n chars to be removed.
ex: Jsoup.clean("a  \n   b", Whitelist.none()) returns "a b"

Comment: @Keith: of course extra spaces and \n will be removed as HTML ignores them and you are calling .clean()

Comment: Will this perform 'attribute escape' as well? I am specifically referring to Rule #2 in this list:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_.28aka_Output_Encoding.29

Comment: @Nels: you're talking about `Jsoup#clean()`? Yes definitely. Click the "Jsoup#clean()" link in my previous comment.

Comment: Alas, it removed new lines. And we need them :)

Comment: input.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

Comment: @Zeroows: this fails miserably on `<p>Lorem ipsum 1 < 3 dolor sit amet</p>`. Again, [HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157882). It's completely beyond me why everyone keeps trying to throw regex on it to parse parts of interest instead of using a real parser.

Comment: I also found this answer not satisfying against XSS and I posted another answer.

Comment: That is WAY better than `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: use `Jsoup.clean(unsafeString, "", Whitelist.none(), new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));` to preserve linebreaks

Comment: compile this : compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'

Comment: It may be better, but it introduces another dependency to your project which is not good

Comment: Didn't work for the input text, "Hi <span>there! Please don't use <and >"

Comment: Can someone elaborate what makes this better than Html.fromHtml(..).toString()?

Comment: @FrankKrumnow: `Html.fromHtml(..).toString()` isn't available in standard Java nor as a standard Java library. It's only available in Android.

Comment: My bad. Did see the question in an android context.

Comment: I've just realized that this answer implies HTML string. What about if we're talking about general string? I.e. there's no way to turn off escaping lt, gt, amp, quot. If string contains &, JSoup will clean it as &amp. (tried to use it for JSON string sanitation, to prevent XSS)

Comment: @jalmasi: just traverse JSON and sanitize each string property instead of the whole JSON object itself. Or, if your JSON parser supports it, register a new listener/adapter/whateverTheyCallIt so that your JSON parser does it automatically.

Comment: @BalusC that's exactly what I'm doing - jackson, de/serializer for by type. But Jsoup cleaner replaces gt, lt, amp, quot no matter what, and there's no way to turn that off. I.e. there's no EscapeMode.none :)

Comment: This is not working for me, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861739/how-to-parse-text-with-html-tags-into-plain-text

Answer (score 304):

If you're writing for **Android** you can do this...

androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat.fromHtml(instruction,HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()

Comment: Awesome tip. :) If you're displaying the text in a TextView, you can drop the .toString() to preserve some formatting, too.

Comment: @Branky It doesn't I have tried...the accepted answer works like charm

Comment: This is good, but <img> tags are replaced with some bizarre things. I got small squares where there was an image

Comment: @BibaswannBandyopadhyay [another answer helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560045/android-getting-obj-using-textview-settextcharactersequence) getting rid of these characters

Comment: use package `androidx.core.text` instead of legacy `android.text`

Answer (score 98):

If the user enters `<b>hey!</b>`, do you want to display `<b>hey!</b>` or `hey!`?  If the first, escape less-thans, and html-encode ampersands (and optionally quotes) and you're fine.  A modification to your code to implement the second option would be:

```
replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")
```

but you will run into issues if the user enters something malformed, like `<bhey!</b>`.

You can also check out [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) which will parse "dirty" html input, and should give you a way to remove the tags, keeping the text.

The problem with trying to strip html is that browsers have very lenient parsers, more lenient than any library you can find will, so even if you do your best to strip all tags (using the replace method above, a DOM library, or JTidy), you will *still* need to make sure to encode any remaining HTML special characters to keep your output safe.

Comment: You also run into issues, if there is unescaped < or > sign inside the html node content. <span>My age is < a lot's of text > then your age</span>. i think that only 100% way to do this is via some XML DOM interface (like SAX or similar), to use node.getText().

Comment: This does working for string like "\r\n HDFC Bank <\/a>\r\n <\/div>\r\n <\/td>\r\n"

Answer (score 31):

Another way is to use  *javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit* to extract the text.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;

public class Html2Text extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {
    StringBuffer s;

    public Html2Text() {
    }

    public void parse(Reader in) throws IOException {
        s = new StringBuffer();
        ParserDelegator delegator = new ParserDelegator();
        // the third parameter is TRUE to ignore charset directive
        delegator.parse(in, this, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public void handleText(char[] text, int pos) {
        s.append(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return s.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // the HTML to convert
            FileReader in = new FileReader("java-new.html");
            Html2Text parser = new Html2Text();
            parser.parse(in);
            in.close();
            System.out.println(parser.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of "a < b or b > c" is "a b or b > c", which seems unfortunate.

Comment: This worked the best for me. I needed to preserve line breaks. I did by adding this simple method to the parser: @Override public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) { if (t == HTML.Tag.P || t == HTML.Tag.BR) { s.append('\n'); } }

Comment: dfrankow: The mathematical expression a < b or b > c should be written in html like this: a &lt; b or b &gt; c

Comment: I love that this doesn't have external dependencies.

Answer (score 28):

I think that the simpliest way to filter the html tags is:

```
private static final Pattern REMOVE_TAGS = Pattern.compile("<.+?>");

public static String removeTags(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return string;
    }

    Matcher m = REMOVE_TAGS.matcher(string);
    return m.replaceAll("");
}
```

Comment: Two things missing: special character decoding, tags p and br; optionally you want to omit script content.

Answer (score 20):

On Android, try this:

```
String result = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
```

Comment: This did it! it removed all inline html from text :)

Comment: You are always using code snippets for normal code. Code Snippets are only supposed to be used for HTML or javascript or other code which can be run in the browser. You cannot run Java in the browser. Use normal code blocks in the future... I will edit your answer for you this time and fix the formatting etc, but please don't do this anymore in the future. This isn't the first time I told you about this...

Comment: What library is this coming from?

Comment: @PaulCroarkin this is the library inside android sdk . android.text.Html

Comment: But this is adding plenty of white spaces or new lines to the end of my string. Not cool.

Comment: works fine for me man, may be you should check your input, like does it comes with any white space like that..

Comment: Awesome. Removed all html tags.

Comment: looks familiar, like my answer from 2011.

Comment: that removed another headache from my plate :)

Comment: Helped a lot. This works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Also very simple using [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), and you can retain some of the formatting (line breaks and links, for example).

```
    Source htmlSource = new Source(htmlText);
    Segment htmlSeg = new Segment(htmlSource, 0, htmlSource.length());
    Renderer htmlRend = new Renderer(htmlSeg);
    System.out.println(htmlRend.toString());
```

Comment: Jericho was able to parse <br> to a line break. Jsoup and HTMLEditorKit could not do that.

Comment: Jericho is very capable of doing this job, used it a lot in owned projects.

Comment: Jericho worked like a charm.  Thanks for the suggestion.  One note: you don't have to create a Segment of the whole string.  Source extends Segment, so either works in the Renderer constructor.

Comment: Jerico now seems to be a bit dated ( the last release was 3.4 in late 2015). However, if it still works well, then it still works well!

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer of doing simply `Jsoup.parse(html).text()` has 2 potential issues (with JSoup 1.7.3):

- It removes line breaks from the text
- It converts text `&lt;script&gt;` into `<script>`

If you use this to protect against XSS, this is a bit annoying. Here is my best shot at an improved solution, using both JSoup and Apache StringEscapeUtils:

```
// breaks multi-level of escaping, preventing &amp;lt;script&amp;gt; to be rendered as <script>
String replace = input.replace("&amp;", "");
// decode any encoded html, preventing &lt;script&gt; to be rendered as <script>
String html = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(replace);
// remove all html tags, but maintain line breaks
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "", Whitelist.none(), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
// decode html again to convert character entities back into text
return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(clean);
```

Note that the last step is because I need to use the output as plain text. If you need only HTML output then you should be able to remove it.

And here is a bunch of test cases (input to output):

```
{"regular string", "regular string"},
{"<a href=\"link\">A link</a>", "A link"},
{"<script src=\"http://evil.url.com\"/>", ""},
{"&lt;script&gt;", ""},
{"&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;", "lt;scriptgt;"}, // best effort
{"\" ' > < \n \\ é å à ü and & preserved", "\" ' > < \n \\ é å à ü and & preserved"}
```

If you find a way to make it better, please let me know.

Comment: This will fail against something like `&#38;lt;script&#38;gt;alert('Evil script executed');&#38;lt;/script&#38;gt;`. Same goes for `&#x26;`. JSoup does not convert `&lt;script&gt; into <script>`, it does that because you call `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` after JSoup cleaned up the input.

Answer (score 12):

HTML Escaping is really hard to do right- I'd definitely suggest using library code to do this, as it's a lot more subtle than you'd think. Check out Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) for a pretty good library for handling this in Java.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm looking for but I want to strip the HTML instead of escaping it.

Comment: do you want to strip the html, or do you want to convert it to plain text? Stripping the HTML from a long string with br tags and HTML entities can result in an illegible mess.

Comment: Have you tried StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml? from commons-lang?

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml does not strip html

Comment: Good information on utils to use for unescaping but not answering the question.

Comment: Confusing answer. Removing != Unescaping

Answer (score 12):

This should work -

use this

```
  text.replaceAll('<.*?>' , " ") -> This will replace all the html tags with a space.
```

and this

```
  text.replaceAll('&.*?;' , "")-> this will replace all the tags which starts with "&" and ends with ";" like &nbsp;, &amp;, &gt; etc.
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more useful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do.

Comment: @Sandeep1699 No explanation of the answer at all? Not good.

Answer (score 9):

**You can simply use the Android's default HTML filter**

```
    public String htmlToStringFilter(String textToFilter){

    return Html.fromHtml(textToFilter).toString();

    }
```

The above method will return the HTML filtered string for your input.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Html'

Answer (score 7):

You might want to replace `<br/>` and `</p>` tags with newlines before stripping the HTML to prevent it becoming an illegible mess as Tim suggests.

The only way I can think of removing HTML tags but leaving non-HTML between angle brackets would be check against a [list of HTML tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp). Something along these lines...

```
replaceAll("\\<[\s]*tag[^>]*>","")
```

Then HTML-decode special characters such as `&amp;`. The result should not be considered to be sanitized.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a lightly more fleshed out update to try to handle some formatting for breaks and lists. I used Amaya's output as a guide.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;

public class HTML2Text extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {
    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    private StringBuffer stringBuffer;

    private Stack<IndexType> indentStack;

    public static class IndexType {
        public String type;
        public int counter; // used for ordered lists

        public IndexType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    public HTML2Text() {
        stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        indentStack = new Stack<IndexType>();
    }

    public static String convert(String html) {
        HTML2Text parser = new HTML2Text();
        Reader in = new StringReader(html);
        try {
            // the HTML to convert
            parser.parse(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // this should never happen
            }
        }
        return parser.getText();
    }

    public void parse(Reader in) throws IOException {
        ParserDelegator delegator = new ParserDelegator();
        // the third parameter is TRUE to ignore charset directive
        delegator.parse(in, this, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
        log.info("StartTag:" + t.toString());
        if (t.toString().equals("p")) {
            if (stringBuffer.length() > 0
                    && !stringBuffer.substring(stringBuffer.length() - 1)
                            .equals("\n")) {
                newLine();
            }
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("ol")) {
            indentStack.push(new IndexType("ol"));
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("ul")) {
            indentStack.push(new IndexType("ul"));
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("li")) {
            IndexType parent = indentStack.peek();
            if (parent.type.equals("ol")) {
                String numberString = "" + (++parent.counter) + ".";
                stringBuffer.append(numberString);
                for (int i = 0; i < (4 - numberString.length()); i++) {
                    stringBuffer.append(" ");
                }
            } else {
                stringBuffer.append("*   ");
            }
            indentStack.push(new IndexType("li"));
        } else if (t.toString().equals("dl")) {
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("dt")) {
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("dd")) {
            indentStack.push(new IndexType("dd"));
            newLine();
        }
    }

    private void newLine() {
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < indentStack.size(); i++) {
            stringBuffer.append("    ");
        }
    }

    public void handleEndTag(HTML.Tag t, int pos) {
        log.info("EndTag:" + t.toString());
        if (t.toString().equals("p")) {
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("ol")) {
            indentStack.pop();
            ;
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("ul")) {
            indentStack.pop();
            ;
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("li")) {
            indentStack.pop();
            ;
            newLine();
        } else if (t.toString().equals("dd")) {
            indentStack.pop();
            ;
        }
    }

    public void handleSimpleTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
        log.info("SimpleTag:" + t.toString());
        if (t.toString().equals("br")) {
            newLine();
        }
    }

    public void handleText(char[] text, int pos) {
        log.info("Text:" + new String(text));
        stringBuffer.append(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String html = "<html><body><p>paragraph at start</p>hello<br />What is happening?<p>this is a<br />mutiline paragraph</p><ol>  <li>This</li>  <li>is</li>  <li>an</li>  <li>ordered</li>  <li>list    <p>with</p>    <ul>      <li>another</li>      <li>list        <dl>          <dt>This</dt>          <dt>is</dt>            <dd>sdasd</dd>            <dd>sdasda</dd>            <dd>asda              <p>aasdas</p>            </dd>            <dd>sdada</dd>          <dt>fsdfsdfsd</dt>        </dl>        <dl>          <dt>vbcvcvbcvb</dt>          <dt>cvbcvbc</dt>            <dd>vbcbcvbcvb</dd>          <dt>cvbcv</dt>          <dt></dt>        </dl>        <dl>          <dt></dt>        </dl></li>      <li>cool</li>    </ul>    <p>stuff</p>  </li>  <li>cool</li></ol><p></p></body></html>";
        System.out.println(convert(html));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One more way can be to use com.google.gdata.util.common.html.HtmlToText class 
like

```
MyWriter.toConsole(HtmlToText.htmlToPlainText(htmlResponse));
```

This is not bullet proof code though and when I run it on wikipedia entries I am getting style info also. However I believe for small/simple jobs this would be effective.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me for the test case I indicated: the result of "a < b or b > c" is "a b or b > c".

So, I used TagSoup instead.  Here's a shot that worked for my test case (and a couple of others):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

/**
 * Take HTML and give back the text part while dropping the HTML tags.
 *
 * There is some risk that using TagSoup means we'll permute non-HTML text.
 * However, it seems to work the best so far in test cases.
 *
 * @author dan
 * @see <a href="http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/">TagSoup</a> 
 */
public class Html2Text2 implements ContentHandler {
private StringBuffer sb;

public Html2Text2() {
}

public void parse(String str) throws IOException, SAXException {
    XMLReader reader = new Parser();
    reader.setContentHandler(this);
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    reader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(str)));
}

public String getText() {
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < length; idx++) {
    sb.append(ch[idx+start]);
    }
}

@Override
public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {
    sb.append(ch);
}

// The methods below do not contribute to the text
@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
}


@Override
public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
    throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
}

@Override
public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
}

@Override
public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
    throws SAXException {
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, one can use [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/index.php):

```
private CharSequence removeHtmlFrom(String html) {
    return new HtmlCleaner().clean(html).getText();
}
```

Comment: HtmlCleaner works well, keeps line breaks and has a recent release (2.21 in May 2017).

Answer (score 5):

Use **`Html.fromHtml`**

***HTML*** Tags are

```
<a href=”…”> <b>,  <big>, <blockquote>, <br>, <cite>, <dfn>
<div align=”…”>,  <em>, <font size=”…” color=”…” face=”…”>
<h1>,  <h2>, <h3>, <h4>,  <h5>, <h6>
<i>, <p>, <small>
<strike>,  <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <tt>, <u>
```

As per **[Android’s official Documentations](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/Html.html)** any  tags in the **HTML** will display as a generic replacement **String** which your program can then go through and replace with real ***strings***.

**`Html.formHtml`** method takes an **`Html.TagHandler`** and an Html.ImageGetter as arguments as well as the text to parse.

### Example

```
String Str_Html=" <p>This is about me text that the user can put into their profile</p> ";
```

Then

```
Your_TextView_Obj.setText(Html.fromHtml(Str_Html).toString());
```

Output

**This is about me text that the user can put into their profile**

Comment: No extra utilities and aligns with Android Docs. +1

Answer (score 5):

Here is one more variant of how to replace all(HTML Tags |  HTML Entities | Empty Space in HTML content)

`content.replaceAll("(<.*?>)|(&.*?;)|([ ]{2,})", "");` where content is a String.

Comment: I improved it a bit:
{code}
.replaceAll("(<.*?>)|(&.*?;)", " ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")
{code}
Because often those tags are just next to text. And after removing tags change all 2 and more writespaces to just 1.

Comment: This answer would take cake

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to go from HTML to plain text.
If that is the case look at www.htmlparser.org.  Here is an example that strips all the tags out from the html file found at a URL.
It makes use of *org.htmlparser.beans.StringBean*.

```
static public String getUrlContentsAsText(String url) {
    String content = "";
    StringBean stringBean = new StringBean();
    stringBean.setURL(url);
    content = stringBean.getStrings();
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I was just working on a project that required me to filter HTML and this worked fine:

```
noHTMLString.replaceAll("\\&.*?\\;", "");
```

instead of this:

```
html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;","");
html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"."");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it:

```
public static String removeHTML(String input) {
    int i = 0;
    String[] str = input.split("");

    String s = "";
    boolean inTag = false;

    for (i = input.indexOf("<"); i < input.indexOf(">"); i++) {
        inTag = true;
    }
    if (!inTag) {
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            s = s + str[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Or you can just say, 
if(input.indexOf("<") > 0 || input.indexOf(">") > 0) return ""; else return input;

Answer (score 2):

One could also use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) for this purpose. By default it preserves whitespaces from the stripped html, which may be desired in certain situations:

```java
InputStream htmlInputStream = ..
HtmlParser htmlParser = new HtmlParser();
HtmlContentHandler htmlContentHandler = new HtmlContentHandler();
htmlParser.parse(htmlInputStream, htmlContentHandler, new Metadata())
System.out.println(htmlContentHandler.getBodyText().trim())
```

Comment: Note that the parse method is deprecated in favor of `Parse.parse(InputStream, ContentHandler, Metadata, ParseContext)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to retain new-line info with JSoup is to precede all new line tags with some dummy string, execute JSoup and replace dummy string with "\n".

```
String html = "<p>Line one</p><p>Line two</p>Line three<br/>etc.";
String NEW_LINE_MARK = "NEWLINESTART1234567890NEWLINEEND";
for (String tag: new String[]{"</p>","<br/>","</h1>","</h2>","</h3>","</h4>","</h5>","</h6>","</li>"}) {
    html = html.replace(tag, NEW_LINE_MARK+tag);
}

String text = Jsoup.parse(html).text();

text = text.replace(NEW_LINE_MARK + " ", "\n\n");
text = text.replace(NEW_LINE_MARK, "\n\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
classeString.replaceAll("\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>", "\\ ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the html string come from xml  with such `&lt`. When using Jsoup we need parse it and then clean it.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlstrl);
Whitelist wl = Whitelist.none();
String plain = Jsoup.clean(doc.text(), wl);
```

While only using `Jsoup.parse(htmlstrl).text()` can't remove tags.

Comment: What is "Whitelist" here ?

Comment: Not working for "\r\n HDFC Bank <\/a>\r\n <\/div>\r\n <\/td>\r\n", I replaced `Whitelist` with `Safelist`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this for javascript:**

```js
const strippedString = htmlString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
console.log(strippedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to remove the HTML tags from the String,

```
public static String stripHtmlTags(String html) {

    return html.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you saw the comment on the accepted answer (from 2010) that says - try this `<p>Lorem ipsum 1 < 3 dolor sit amet</p>` and see how well the regex works ..

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents:

```
String[] temp = yourString.split("&amp;");
String tmp = "";
if (temp.length > 1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        tmp += temp[i] + "&";
    }
    yourString = tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get **formateed plain html text** you can do that:

```
String BR_ESCAPED = "&lt;br/&gt;";
Element el=Jsoup.parse(html).select("body");
el.select("br").append(BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("p").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("h1").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("h2").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("h3").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("h4").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
el.select("h5").append(BR_ESCAPED+BR_ESCAPED);
String nodeValue=el.text();
nodeValue=nodeValue.replaceAll(BR_ESCAPED, "<br/>");
nodeValue=nodeValue.replaceAll("(\\s*<br[^>]*>){3,}", "<br/><br/>");
```

To get **formateed plain text** change <br/> by \n and change last line by:

```
nodeValue=nodeValue.replaceAll("(\\s*\n){3,}", "<br/><br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is been a while since this question as been asked, but I found another solution, this is what worked for me:

```
Pattern REMOVE_TAGS = Pattern.compile("<.+?>");
    Source source= new Source(htmlAsString);
 Matcher m = REMOVE_TAGS.matcher(sourceStep.getTextExtractor().toString());
                        String clearedHtml= m.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that if you're trying to accomplish this in a [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net/) project, it's already a built-in string extension

```
using ServiceStack.Text;
// ...
"The <b>quick</b> brown <p> fox </p> jumps over the lazy dog".StripHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

I often find that I only need to strip out comments and script elements. This has worked reliably for me for 15 years and can easily be extended to handle any element name in HTML or XML:

```
// delete all comments
response = response.replaceAll("<!--[^>]*-->", "");
// delete all script elements
response = response.replaceAll("<(script|SCRIPT)[^+]*?>[^>]*?<(/script|SCRIPT)>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove HTML tags including line breaks.

```
function remove_html_tags(html) {
    html = html.replace(/<div>/g, "").replace(/<\/div>/g, "<br>");
    html = html.replace(/<br>/g, "$br$");
    html = html.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '$br$');
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    html = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
    html = html.replace(/\$br\$/g, "\n");
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply make a method with multiple replaceAll() like

```
String RemoveTag(String html){
   html = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")
   html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;","");
   html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"."");
   ----------
   ----------
   return html;
}
```

Use this link for most common replacements you need:
http://tunes.org/wiki/html_20special_20characters_20and_20symbols.html

It is simple but effective. I use this method first to remove the junk but not the very first line i.e replaceAll("\<.*?>",""), and later i use specific keywords to search for indexes and then use .substring(start, end) method to strip away unnecessary stuff. As this is more robust and you can pin point exactly what you need in the entire html page.

Comment: Two notes. First, this is suboptimal - for each replaceAll call, Java will attempt to compile the first argument as a regex and run through the entire string to apply that regex to the string, processing a few dozen KB for a regular HTML page every time. Second, it's advised not to use replaceAll to replace simple (non-regex) strings, but instead use replace() (which also replaces all, unlike the name suggests).

Answer (score -1):

Remove HTML tags from string. Somewhere we need to parse some string which is received by some responses like Httpresponse from the server.

So we need to parse it.

Here I will show how to remove html tags from string.

```
    // sample text with tags

    string str = "<html><head>sdfkashf sdf</head><body>sdfasdf</body></html>";



    // regex which match tags

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]*>");



    // replace all matches with empty strin

    str = rx.Replace(str, "");



    //now str contains string without html tags
```

Comment: Where do you get `new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex();` from?

Comment: @beresfordt this response applies to .NET, not Java like was requested in the question