# Getting raw text from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

In my application, I use a `JTextPane` to display some log information. As I want to hightlight some specific lines in this text (for example the error messages), I set the `contentType` as "`text/html`". This way, I can format my text.

Now, I create a JButton that copies the content of this `JTextPane` into the clipboard. That part is easy, but my problem is that when I call `myTextPane.getText()`, I get the HTML code, such as :

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    blabla<br>
    <font color="#FFCC66"><b>foobar</b></font><br>
    blabla
  </body>
</html>
```

instead of getting only the raw content:

```
blabla
foobar
blabla
```

Is there a way to get only the content of my `JTextPane` in plain text? Or do I need to transform the HTML into raw text by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer to: [Removing HTML from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

```
MyHtml2Text parser = new MyHtml2Text();
try {
    parser.parse(new StringReader(myTextPane.getText()));
} catch (IOException ee) {
  //handle exception
}
System.out.println(parser.getText());
```

Slightly modified version of the `Html2Text` class found on the answer I linked to

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;

public class MyHtml2Text extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {
    StringBuffer s;
    public MyHtml2Text() {}
    public void parse(Reader in) throws IOException {
        s = new StringBuffer();
        ParserDelegator delegator = new ParserDelegator();
        delegator.parse(in, this, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    public void handleText(char[] text, int pos) {
        s.append(text);
        s.append("\n");
    }
    public String getText() {
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

If you need a more fine-grained handling consider implementing more of the interface defined by [`HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback.html)

Answer (score 18):

No need to use the ParserCallback. Just use:

```
textPane.getDocument().getText(0, textPane.getDocument().getLength()) );
```

Comment: That's indeed a really good solution... except that I lost all the line breaks, and then my final String is only in one line. Too bad, because I really liked this solution!

Comment: Yes, the Document doesn't store line breaks, they where manually added by the other solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it yourself unfortunately. Imagine if some of the contents was HTML specific, eg images - the text representation is unclear. Include alt text or not for instance.

Answer (score 2):

(Is RegExp allowed? This isn't parsing, isn't it)

Take the getText() result and use String.replaceAll() to filter all tags. Than a trim() to remove leading and trailing whitespaces. For the whitespaces between your first and you last 'blabla' I don't see a general solution. Maybe you can spilt the rest around CRLF and trim all Strings again.

(I'm no regexp expert - maybe someone can provide the regexp and earn some reputation ;) )

**Edit**

.. I just assumed that you don't use `<` and `>` in your text - otherwise it.. say, it's a challenge.