# How to get text content of JEditorPane contentType is text/html?

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

Is there a way to get plain text content of jEditorPane whose contentType is text/html?
Using `jEditorPane.getText()` gives the whole html code plugged in the EditorPane.

Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859686/getting-raw-text-from-jtextpane