# Prevent HTML JTextPane from formatting text input

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've written a sample application that consists of a `JTextPane` and a button that prints out the contents of the text pane. The text pane's content type is set to "text/html".

When I enter some text and print it out to console, the text is automatically wrapped.

For example, given the following input:

```
Watercress shallot radish chickweed bitterleaf bush tomato salad garlic beet greens black-eyed pea green bean salsify bell pepper. Catsear celery green bean broccoli rabe spring onion tatsoi prairie turnip wattle seed cucumber burdock. Chickweed cucumber chickpea bush tomato wakame taro fava bean arugula catsear azuki bean.
```

The output comes out as such

```
Watercress shallot radish chickweed bitterleaf bush tomato salad garlic 
beet greens black-eyed pea green bean salsify bell pepper. Catsear celery 
green bean broccoli rabe spring onion tatsoi prairie turnip wattle seed 
cucumber burdock. Chickweed cucumber chickpea bush tomato wakame taro fava 
bean arugula catsear azuki bean.
```

Is there a way to preserve the format of the input text? I am planning to store the input in a database, so I'm replacing new-line characters with `<br>`, but the text pane is automatically inserting its own new-lines.

If there are alternate solutions I could try those as well, but for the most part I want to be able to display HTML while allowing users to modify input.

Here is the code for the sample. You should be able to just compile and run it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame {

    private JTextPane textPane = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TextPaneTest();
    }

    public TextPaneTest() {

        // Main panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Panel holding text
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Text pane
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");

        // Button
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Print Text");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                String text = textPane.getText();
                text = text.substring(text.indexOf("<body>") + 6, text.indexOf("</body>"));
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        });

        textPanel.add(textPane);
        panel.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Add everything to the frame
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(1000, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So .. given you are intending to insert newlines programmatically, why not use a `JTextArea` or a `JTextPane` set to `text/plain`?

Comment: Sorry if there is any confusion. New-lines aren't being inserted programmatically; any that is inserted by the user is converted to `<br>`'s.

Comment: *"New-lines aren't being inserted programmatically;.."* OK, but it does not change my advice.  Simply swap the newlines the user inputs, for whatever is actually needed.

Comment: Is there a way to keep it as an HTML textpane, while preventing the textpane from adding its own new-lines?

Comment: Create your own [`HTMLEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html)?

Comment: This question led me to some alternative ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859686/getting-raw-text-from-jtextpane

Answer (score 1):

```
    textPane.setText("<html><head><style type='text/css'>"
            + "body{white-space:nowrap;}"
            + "</style></head><body>");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    //Remove: textPanel.add(textPane);
    textPanel.add(scrollPane);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The HTML CSS removes the wrapping. Remains having a horizontal scrollbar.
Furthermore you probably can do with a `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` especially when running in an IDE.