# Cleaning a string consisting of html/server-side tags in Java

Tags: java, html

I have a text like:

I've got a date with this fellow tomorrow. Well me and thousands of others. <br /><br /><img src="http://www.newwest.net/images/thumbnails_feature/barack_obama_westerners.jpg"><br /><br />Tomorrow morning I will be getting up at stupid o'clock and driving up to Manchester, NH to see Barak Obama speak. <br /><br />You all should come too!<br /><br /><a href="http://nh.barackobama.com/manchesterchange">RSVP for the event</a>

I would want to like to clean it too :

> I've got a date with this fellow
>   tomorrow. Well me and thousands of
>   others
>   http://www.newwest.net/images/thumbnails_feature/barack_obama_westerners.jpg
>   Tomorrow morning I
>   will be getting up at stupid
>   o'clock and driving up to
>   Manchester, NH to see Barak Obama
>   speak.You all
>   should come too!
>   h**p://nh.barackobama.com/manchesterchange RSVP
>   for the event

I would like to write a JAVA program for the same. Any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated.The tags aren't limited to the above post. This was just an example.

Thanks!

PS: Replace *'s by t's in the second hyperlink as Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to post more than one link.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488967/java-remove-html-from-string-without-regular-expressions

Comment: You extract the urls from within the html tags (`src`, `href`). Should `<div id="noscript-padding">`also result in `noscript-padding`?

Comment: Hi Ash, 
I did go through the link before asking this question. The difference in both however, is that here I am receiving an XML file (not well formed and hence can't use an XML parser!). I have extracted a certain portion of it using regular expressions. However, that particular extracted portion contains such HTML/Server-side tags. I want to remove it. Is JTidy/Jericho a good option?

Comment: Hi Peter, I couldn't quite understand your question. To add, It's just not the <br></br> and <href> tags. There are also tags like "&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt", "&#039" , "&lt;div class=&quot" etc. present.

Comment: @Denzil: Your result still contains text from within html tags (the urls of the image and of the link). For a generic parser, the xml for `<a href="about:blank">` looks the same as `<div id="noscript-padding">`. How do you know which attributes to keep and which ones to ignore?

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your patience. I want to ignore all the tags like  the one's in my comment above. I would only like to keep the complete http links.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: Bozho, The "javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit" may not work for the fact that my file is not a HTML file. It's NOT well formed HTML or XML for that matter. It's a text file which contains a block of text and unfortunately the text has HTML tags like the ones mentioned in the comments above to Peter Lang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of 'tidying' text which has XML tags is to use a regular expression that identifies anything that is a tag (i.e. anything that starts with '<' and ends with '>' and everything in between). Note this works whether or not XML is 'well-formed' as it cleans up any tags regardless of whether opening tags match with closing tags.

For example,

```
String noXmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

will remove all tags from a given string. The downside is that it won't preserve the image link nor the hyperlink as per your example. Hope this helps though!

Edited 11:58 04/04/10: Try this to remove HTML encoded HTML tags (i.e.. anything that starts with `&lt;` and ends with `&gt;`)...

```
String noHtmlHtmlString = htmlHtmlString.replaceAll("&lt;.+?&gt;", "");
```

Then to remove any other HTML encoded/formatted bits like `&quot;` (i.e. anything that starts with & and ends with ; and in between conforms to a valid word without spaces or breaks) use

```
String noHtmlEncodingString = htmlEncodingString.replaceAll("&\\w+?;", "");
```

If there's any malformed HTML/XML beyond those, unless there's a known pattern there's no way of catching them.

Comment: Hi David, 
The "javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit" may not work for the fact that my file is not a HTML file. It's NOT well formed HTML or XML for that matter. It's a text file which contains a block of text and unfortunately the text has HTML tags like the ones mentioned in the comments above to Peter Lang.

Comment: &lt;br /&gt; seems to be an HTML encoded version of rendering <br />, so it's HTML for rendering HTML to show a user! I can add another regex in my solution for you to remove those.

Answer (score 1):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want. I just tried it by saving the block of text in your post as `test.txt`, and ran JTidy with these options:

```
java -jar jtidy-r938.jar -asxml test.txt >test.html
```

It produced the following well-formed XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator"
content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 2009-12-01), see jtidy.sourceforge.net" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
I've got a date with this fellow tomorrow. Well me and thousands of
others. <br />
<br />
<img
src="http://www.newwest.net/images/thumbnails_feature/barack_obama_westerners.jpg" /><br />
<br />
Tomorrow morning I will be getting up at stupid o'clock and driving
up to Manchester, NH to see Barak Obama speak. <br />
<br />
You all should come too!<br />
<br />
<a href="http://nh.barackobama.com/manchesterchange">RSVP for the
event</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use the API instead of the command line, you will be able to extract the bits you are interested in and discard the rest.

Comment: Jason, Thanks for the reply. I will check JTidy and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out an HTML parser such as [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). Despite its name it will parse HTML and provide a useful API to allow you to extract what you need.

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thanks for the reply. The problem is that it isn't an HTML file. It's just a block of text. I am not sure if JTidy/Jericho would help as there's no tags like <body> <table> etc.

Comment: JTidy was my initial idea, but what he actually wants is to get rid of all tags whatsoever.

Comment: Bozho, I will try JTidy and reply. I am not sure if JTidy is able to process a block of text (not well formed HTML) and return a clean block of text.