# Java how can I add an accented "e" to a string?

Tags: java, html, parsing, character, diacritics

With the help of tucuxi from the existing post [Java remove HTML from String without regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488967/java-remove-html-from-string-without-regular-expressions) I have built a method that will parse out any basic HTML tags from a string. Sometimes, however, the original string contains html hexadecimal characters like &#x00E9 (which is an accented e). I have started to add functionality which will translate these escaped characters into real characters.

You're probably asking: Why not use regular expressions? Or a third party library? Unfortunately I cannot, as I am developing on a BlackBerry platform which does not support regular expressions and I have never been able to successfully add a third party library to my project.

So, I have gotten to the point where any &#x00E9 is replaced with "e". My question now is, how do I add an actual 'accented e' to a string?

Here is my code:

public static String removeHTML(String synopsis) {

```
char[] cs = synopsis.toCharArray();
  String sb = new String();
  boolean tag = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
   switch (cs[i]) {
   case '<':
    if (!tag) {
     tag = true;
     break;
    }
   case '>':
    if (tag) {
     tag = false;
     break;
    }
   case '&':

    char[] copyTo = new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(cs, i, copyTo, 0, 7);

    String result = new String(copyTo);

    if (result.equals("&#x00E9")) {
     sb += "e";
    }

    i += 7;
    break;
   default:
    if (!tag)
     sb += cs[i];
   }
  }

  return sb.toString();
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Joel: I was wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Strings are unicode.

```
sb += '\u00E9';   # lower case  e + '
sb += '\u00C9';   # upper case  E + '
```

Comment: is there a full guide for the other codes like ô ù ..?

Comment: I found [this guide for common special Latin characters in Java](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0136.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can print out just about any character you like in Java as it uses the Unicode character set.

To find the character you want take a look at the charts here:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

In the Latin Supplement document you'll see all the unicode numbers for the accented characters. You should see the hex number 00E9 listed for é for example. The numbers for all Latin accented characters  are in this document so you should find this pretty useful.

To print use character in a String, just use the Unicode escape sequence of \u followed by the character code like so:

```
System.out.print("Let's go to the caf\u00E9");
```

Would produce: "Let's go to the café"

Depending in which version of Java you're using you might find StringBuilders (or StringBuffers if you're multi-threaded) more efficient than using the + operator to concatenate Strings too.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  if (result.equals("&#x00E9")) {
     sb += char(130);
    }
```

instead of

```
  if (result.equals("&#x00E9")) {
     sb += "e";
    }
```

The thing is that you're not adding an accent to the top of the 'e' character, but rather that is a separate character all together.  This [site](http://www.asciitable.com/) lists out the ascii codes for characters.

Answer (score 0):

For a table of accented in characters in Java [take a look at this reference](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0136.html).

To decode the html part, use Apache [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

`import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(yourString);`

See also this Stack Overflow thread:
[Replace HTML codes with equivalent characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998726/replace-html-codes-with-equivalent-characters-in-java)