# Replace HTML codes with equivalent characters in Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matcher

Currently I'm working on converting HTML codes with equivalent characters in java. 
I need to convert the below code to characters.

```
&#x00E8; - è
&#xAE;   - ®
&#x0026; - &
&#x00F1; - ñ
&#x26;   - &
```

I tried using the regex pattern

```
(&#x)([\\d|\\w]*)([\\d|\\w]*)([\\d|\\w]*)([\\d|\\w]*)(;)
```

When I debug, `matcher.find()` gives me `true` but the control skips the loop where I have written the code for conversion. Don't know what is happening there.

Also, is there any way to optimize this regex?

Any help is appreciated.

Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "x26"
      at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.commons.lang.Entities.unescape(Entities.java:683)
      at org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.java:483)
```

Comment: It is already answered :). [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Also, is there any way to optimize this regex?

Yes, **don't use regex** for this task, use Apache [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(yourString);
```

JavaDoc says:

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> For example, the string `"&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;"` will become `"<Français>"`
>
> If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim  into the result string. e.g. `"&gt;&zzzz;x"` will become `">&zzzz;x"`.

Comment: Internally it loops over the passed string and use double sized stringBuffer to store the result. Possibly a pre-compiled optimized regex would give you desired result with better performance. What do you think? :)

Comment: @Quoi: I would always use the solution I posted, unless profiling would show that this is a memory or runtime bottleneck, but that was never the case so far and I'm pretty sure never will be.

Comment: I'm getting NumberFormatException for string 'A &#x26; B'

Comment: I thing only entity like '&amp;' will be replaced to '&'. Not the Hex value '&#x26;'. Is that right?

Comment: @RajaAsthana: There's no `NumberFormatException` when I run `String html = "'A &#x26; B'"; String noHtml = unescapeHtml(html);` Your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: @RajaAsthana: For input `"'A &#x26; B'"` you'll get the output `"'A & B'"`.

Comment: Updated the question with the log. Kindly help

Comment: @RajaAsthana: Can you determine which line number in your file/string is causing this problem and post that line, too?

Comment: @RajaAsthana: What version of commons lang are you using? According to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-118) site, this error was fixed in versions 2.1 and newer.

Comment: What to use on Android (Java)?

Comment: by the way, how do we do this in springboot? this is tagged as deprecated in spring boot. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One of all the other possibilities or existing *util* methods could be spring-web's `org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape`.

Example usage in a self-contained Groovy script:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring-web', version='4.3.0.RELEASE')
)
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils

println HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape("La &#xE9;lite del tenis no teme al zika y jugar&#xE1; en R&#xED;o")
```

Comment: This answer is more suitable for Springboot :)