# Load HTML Content to android RichEditText

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using [cwac-richedit](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) librar in my project
user write some text in it and app will save user input as HTML content

my problem is when i want to show saved content to user, it displays as HTML content.
i tried this :

```
Spanned description = Html.fromHtml(stepContent);
rtxtStepDescription.setText(description);
```

and it looks like this

[image: Screenshot]

EDITED:
this is what user writes in edittext:
[image]

app saves this content with `Html.toHtml(rtxtStepDescription.getEditableText())`

after that, next time i open my app this is what app loads:
`<p dir="rtl"><u>&#1587;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;</u><br>
&#1605;&#1578;&#1606; <i>&#1570;&#1586;&#1605;&#1575;&#1740;&#1588;&#1740;</i> &#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740; <b>&#1587;&#1608;&#1575;&#1604;</b></p>`

Comment: Hey, post the value of `stepContent` so that I could try it here if I could get it working

Comment: i will add an example in couple of minutes

Comment: @Darpan Here it is an example of user input

Comment: "this is what the app loads" -- are you saying that is what you are passing into `Html.fromHtml()`? Or are you saying that is what you are getting out of `Html.fromHtml()`?

Comment: This is what is passed to `Html.fromHtml ()` and what getting out of it! And I don't know why

Comment: This answer can help you? see.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599634/convert-html-character-back-to-text-using-java-standard-library , check Zach Scrivena's answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. These are [HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html), See one convertor online [here](http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities).

use Apache [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
...
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(yourString);
```

JavaDoc says:

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.
>
> For example, the string `"&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;"` will become `"<Français>"`
>
> If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim  into the result string. e.g. `"&gt;&zzzz;x"` will become `">&zzzz;x"`.

as described in [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998773/609782)

Comment: it worked because, because of the reasons I mentioned in first two lines :P