# how to convert all identities of a file java

Tags: java, file

i have a File with some character and i have some entities like & è à now i want to add instead of & & amp; and so on..how i can do that? 
If i have Oggi è lunedi & domani è mercoledi
i want that è is replaced by (& grave;) and & is replaced by (& amp;)
I have this code but works only on one identity at a time...

```
 public void genereateFile(String char_speciale, String char_sostituto, String url_scheletro_file, String url_nuovo_file){
            try{
                BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(url_scheletro_file)));
                BufferedWriter wrt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(url_nuovo_file)));
                String line=rdr.readLine();
                while(line!= null){
                    line=line.replaceAll(char_speciale, char_sostituto);
                    wrt.append(line);
                    wrt.newLine();
                    line = rdr.readLine();
                }
                wrt.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: please add an example of what your sample input would look like and the output you want to generate.

Comment: using regular expression like below :
to replace all '&' and 'à ' with a '_'
String new_s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[&à]", "_");


replaceAll is using regular expressions, and using . inside a character class [ ] just recognises a . rather than any character.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are trying to escape/unescape HTML character, maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998726/replace-html-codes-with-equivalent-characters-in-java Solution provided use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but if you want to replace all 'è' and 'à' with '&'

Use regular expression to do that so call your method as

```
genereateFile("[èà]", "&", url_scheletro_file, url_nuovo_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

using regular expression like below : to replace all '&' and 'à ' with a '' String

```
 String new_s = line.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[èà]", "&");
```

[replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is using regular expressions, and using . inside a character class [ ] just recognises a . rather than any character.

EDIT:

```
 public void genereateFile( String char_sostituto, String url_scheletro_file, String url_nuovo_file){
            try{
                BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(url_scheletro_file)));
                BufferedWriter wrt = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(url_nuovo_file)));
                String line=rdr.readLine();
                while(line!= null){
                    line=line.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[èà]", char_sostituto);

                    wrt.append(line);
                    wrt.newLine();
                    line = rdr.readLine();
                }
                wrt.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll(regex, replacement);`  the first argument is the regular expression and if it matches it replace it with the replacement provided.

Check [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))