# Converting json String to UTF-8 in Android

Tags: android, json

I want show **message** from **server** into my application, and i should show this message from `json`.
But message text such as this : `&#274 4;&#276 5;&#272 5;&#273 9;`

I use this code for show message text from `json` :

```
public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {

    ServerResponse resp = response.body();

    if (resp.getResult().equals("success")) {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), reps.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but show `&#274 4;&#276 5;&#272 5;&#273 9;` in Snackbar!!

how can i fix it?

Comment: get me the json response

Comment: @VinayJayaram, Server or Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unscape character before display string. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998726/replace-html-codes-with-equivalent-characters-in-java).

Just to summarize. I suggest you to include in your project the jar commons-lang of Apache foundation in compile dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
```

and then modify your code in this way:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

...

public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
  ServerResponse resp = response.body();
  if (resp.getResult().equals("success")) {
    Snackbar.make(getView(), StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(reps.getMessage()), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thnx my frieeeeeeeeeeeeeend. thnx  <3

Answer (score 0):

You can try and create a new String object out of the response message.

```
String value = new String(reps.getMessage().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

assuming that 'reps.getMessage()' returns String

Comment: show me this error : `Cannot resolve constructor 'String(java.langString, java.lang.String)'`   how can i fix it?

Comment: can you help me? pleaseeee i need this help