# Full reference of the Unicode of accented letters in Java strings

Tags: java, string, unicode

I need to represent accented letters in java string like é è ù ô .. etc , i had found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661126/java-how-can-i-add-an-accented-e-to-a-string) which mentions that we have to use for example `"\u00E9"` to represent `é`, but i need a full reference for all accented letters.

Comment: Will [this](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) help?

Comment: there are many https://emw3.com/unicode-accents.html which one you want?

Comment: @JacobBlanton yes it helps

Comment: You cannot get them. Many accents are done with combining characters (so two character: letter and accent). Then it is a question of font support.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i know that, but i need only the accented letters of french or spanish languages

Comment: So you already know the letters. Note: there is two canonical ways to write such letters in Unicode. Do not assume French and Spanish justs uses "modern standard" accents. Name of places, people and historical document uses more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Eg
U+00E9 -> \u00E9