# convert breaks and paragraph breaks into new line in java

Tags: java, newline, line-breaks

Basically I have an HTML fragment with `<br>` and `<p></p>` inside. I was able to remove all the HTML tags but doing so leaves the text in a bad format.

I want something like [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in PHP except reverse the input and output and also takes into account `<p>` tags. is there a library for it in Java?

Comment: Related: [Removing HTML from a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You basically need to replace each `<br>` with `\n` and each `<p>` with `\n\n`. So, at the points where you succeed to remove them, you need to insert the `\n` and `\n\n` respectively.

Here's a kickoff example with help of the [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) HTML parser (the HTML example is intentionally written that way so that it's hard if not nearly impossible to use regex for this).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String originalHtml = "<p>p1l1<br/><!--</p>-->p1l2<br><!--<p>--></br><p id=p>p2l1<br class=b>p2l2</p>";
    String text = br2nl(originalHtml);
    String newHtml = nl2br(text);

    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println(newHtml);
}

public static String br2nl(String html) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.select("br").append("\\n");
    document.select("p").prepend("\\n\\n");
    return document.text().replace("\\n", "\n");
}

public static String nl2br(String text) {
    return text.replace("\n\n", "<p>").replace("\n", "<br>");
}
```

*(note: `replaceAll()` is unnecessary as we just want a simple charsequence-by-charsequence replacement here, not regexpattern-by-charsequence replacement)*

Output:

```
<p>p1l1<br/><!--</p>-->p1l2<br><!--<p>--></br><p id=p>p2l1<br class=b>p2l2</p>
-------------


p1l1 
p1l2 



p2l1 
p2l2
-------------
<p>p1l1 <br>p1l2 <br> <br> <p>p2l1 <br>p2l2
```

A bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

`br2nl` and `p2nl` are not too complicated. Give this a try:

```
String plain = htmlText.replaceAll("<br>","\\n").replaceAll("<p>","\\n\\n").replaceAll("</p>","");
```

Comment: @BalusC ... yes, an in 'reality' one would use an html parser and add the line.separators while extracting the text to a StringBuilder ;) I had the feeling, the OP used a kind of shortcut ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use replaceAll. See http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0454.html for an example. Just 2 of those, one for p and one for br. The example is going the other way, but you can change it around to replace the html with slash n