# Replacing <br> with a New Line (\n) in JSOUP

Tags: html, jsoup

I'd like to replace all instances of `<br>` with a new line (\n most likely) using Jsoup, but I cannot devise a clean and efficient way of doing so. The resulting `Element#text()` should output no HTML and contain \n in place of where `<br>` was found in the HTML code of the original `Element`.

Comment: view answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132257/convert-breaks-and-paragraph-breaks-into-new-line-in-java

Comment: To embed literal xml/html tags enclose them in back-ticks `\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSoup is Java library, so I assume you're using Java (your question should be then tagged). I've seen a comparison (I didn't wrote the link) where text replacement methods were compared, and **StringUtils** replace methods from **apache-commons** library seemed to be very effective compared to JRE methods, so you should try it.