# Java class to remove HTML tags generated by MSWord

Tags: java, html, ms-word

Some HTML forms are filled by users using copy&paste from MSWord, in FCK editors, or others.
This generates nasty tags annoying other tools to work fine.
Is there a way the server can clean the incoming parameters, so nasty HTML tags would be removed?

Of course, regular expressions are not useful, as long as user can write whatever.

I mean about Java class kinda specialized in this job.

Par example, all this might be replaced by a void string.

```
<p><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Normal</w:View>
<w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
<w:HyphenationZone>21</w:HyphenationZone>
<w:PunctuationKerning />
<w:ValidateAgainstSchemas />
<w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
<w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
<w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
<w:Compatibility>
<w:BreakWrappedTables />
<w:SnapToGridInCell />
<w:WrapTextWithPunct />
<w:UseAsianBreakRules />
<w:DontGrowAutofit />
</w:Compatibility>
<w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" LatentStyleCount="156">
</w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
/* Style Definitions */
table.MsoNormalTable
{mso-style-name:"Tabla normal";
mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
mso-style-noshow:yes;
mso-style-parent:"";
mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
mso-para-margin:0cm;
mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Times New Roman";
mso-ansi-language:#0400;
mso-fareast-language:#0400;
mso-bidi-language:#0400;}
</style>
<![endif]--></p>
```

Comment: Hi. I am having the same problem Have you found out the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Hi, I finally used javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse and works fine

Comment: Hi. How did you used javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse? Can you please paste code? I am still having that issue?

Comment: I used this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/

```
import org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory;
import org.owasp.html.Sanitizers;
```

to build an html accept only policy.  This will get rid of everything except the things you say to include.  Not only will this remove Word Html garbage it will also protect your html input from xss.

```
PolicyFactory policy = (new HtmlPolicyBuilder().allowElements("table", "tr", "td", "th").allowAttributes("style").globally()).toFactory();
        policy = policy.and(Sanitizers.FORMATTING).and(Sanitizers.BLOCKS).and(Sanitizers.IMAGES).and(Sanitizers.LINKS);

String safeHtml = policy.sanitize(html);
```

The problem with JTidy is that it can be quite slow.  The html sanitizer is incredibly fast in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

FCKEditor has a "paste from word" button that works very well.
Could you ask your users to use this functionality?

Comment: Nice, but I need a solution from server as long as other widgets can be applied. And my users won't use the button, lol

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/). It's a Java port of HTMLtidy, which can do the type of cleanup you're looking for. Caveat emptor: I haven't used JTidy and I have no idea how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of CKEditor supports auto detection when you paste from word, which means they wouldn't have to use the button, even though the button is there. it would detect pasting from word and offer to clean it up or convert it to straight text.

Answer (score 0):

docx4j produces clean HTML, which is specifically intended to round trip through CKEditor.