# How do I add the javax.swing.* packages to my libs for my android project?

Tags: android, javax.swing.text

First of all I'd like to mention I am very new to Java programming.  This Android project is my first experience with Java.  So for one task I need to strip HTML tags from a string.  I was thinking about using this answer [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string) to do this task.  In order to do this I need to be able to import javax.swing.text.html.* and javax.swing.text.html.parser.*.

I went to the properties of my project and attempted to add this library to my project.  I read that this was included in the rt.jar file which was located at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar

I was able to use the imports but it seems like it added a million libraries I am not using.  Will this negatively effect my application?  What is the correct way to add just the one extension?

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Android doesn't use Swing. You'll need to use Android's API to create your UI and perform text parsing. Consider `android.text.Html` as a simple way to strip HTML from a string.

Comment: Right, but I need the javax.swing.text.html packages to strip html tags.

Comment: How about using something that Android has? `android.text.Html` can do a blanket-strip of all tags, `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser` is a complex parser (which is probably overkill for your purposes).