# Java packages not importing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to import a bunch of java related API's into my android project but when I import them it says it cannot find the package

here is an example of what I an trying to import

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
```

all the `javax.swing` classes show an error. When I go into where the java JDK was installed and look at the `src.zip` file I see all those classes in there so what do I do to get them to work?

Comment: not sure about this, but I think the swing framework is excluded from the Android platform. Not sure about this tho.

Comment: its not just swing though its also the `java.awt` and I have seen them both used in open source projects

Comment: What would you do with Swing API on your Android app?

Comment: Please see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found after a quick search on the interwebs:

**Swing**

[How do I add the javax.swing.* packages to my libs for my android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230075/how-do-i-add-the-javax-swing-packages-to-my-libs-for-my-android-project)

Synapsis: You can't use swing in your android project

**AWT**

[Using awt with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897775/using-awt-with-android)

Synapsis: You can't use the awt library directly, but you can make your own implementation of it, or use the one linked to [here](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/).

Answer (score 0):

I do no think that you can include java.swing packages in an Android app. I would suggest you take a look at the [User Interface building blocks](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/index.html) that Android provides. Here is a [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230075/how-do-i-add-the-javax-swing-packages-to-my-libs-for-my-android-project) that has a similar discussion about not being able to add java.swing packages.