# Android project build Failure: Java class duplication

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build my android project. I could not understand even if the `**rt.jar**` which contains classes of,

```
 **javax.sound.*.**
 **java.awt.*.**
 **java.awt.**
```

is already there in the jdk1.7/jar folder and also it can be loaded seen under IDE librarie/java but it gives me the error of saying the library classes not found. When i imported the library to the project and build it it says,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/xml/XMLConstants.class
```

duplication error of classes. How come this happen?

Any help will be really appreciated to overcome this issue.

Please find the build.gradle file here,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.sleepApp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0+'
}
```

This is the gradle error:

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
    :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
    > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/xml/XMLConstants.class
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 6.793 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Remove compile files('libs/rt.jar') from your build.gradle file.

Comment: removed it but getting the same error.

Comment: Actually, remove all the compile files('libs/ something') from your build.gradle file

Comment: tried it as well. getting the same error no changes at all. :( im struggling with this for days.

Comment: It means that you are adding javax/xml/XMLConstants twice. check your dependencies

Comment: actually XMLConstants.class is coming default in the jdk(rt.jar) but when i imported it to the project it says class is not found and that is why i put the rt.jar into the library thatz why the duplication happen how to overcome this?

Comment: Ok. Two things: First: Keep the number of dependencies as low as possible. If you are able to compile without any of them, just remove them.  Second: clearly you've got 2 libraries both having XMLConstants.class. You need to find them and get rid of one of them. First find which of the dependencies are bringing this class.

Comment: @pepan actually jdk comes with rt.jar by default but i don't know why my code cannot import them and asking for the classes which is already there in the rt.jar.

Comment: I know what rt.jar is. I don't understand much why you are specifying the import in build.gradle; this is IMHO wrong. In none of my gradle projects I was specifying imports from rt.jar. If gradle complains on class not found, then you probably don't have your android SDK or whatever setup properly.

Comment: @pepan i removed the imports from build.gradle. but it gives me the same errors. :(

Comment: I'm a bit lost, can you please update how the build.gradle looks now?

Comment: sorry for troubling, im struggling with this build for days. :( please check the updated gralde.build thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question u might get and idea about java swing in android platform.

[how to import javax.swing in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544821/how-to-import-javax-swing-in-android-studio)