# ignore user data in html rendering

Tags: html, css

i have user data from database that parse inside `p element`.  if user data contain `</p>` to begin with. my `p element` will be **close**.  how to make the html render and prevent user data manipulating p element?

```
<p style="overflow:auto; position:relative; width:600; height:290;border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: grey;">

<print user data here>

</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bigger problems than the p tag closing incorrectly if you just output user data without checking it first - you need to strip out all unsafe (if not all) HTML tags, **especially `<script>` tags**.

If you're using PHP for example,

`strip_tags('<p>blah</p> <script>dangerousScript()</script>')`

will produce: "blah dangerousScript()", getting rid of both the `<p>` and the `<script>`.

You can supply a list of allowable tags too, if say you want to allow images:

`strip_tags('<p>blah</p> <script>dangerousScript()</script>', '<img>')`

Comment: u are using client side, strip tag? what library?

Comment: @cometta No it's server-side, it's standard PHP. You wouldn't do this client-side, you'd do it immediately after you extract the data from the database on the server.

Comment: @cometta, I just noticed that you're using Java. Look at this for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the text and make it HTML-friendly. At a bare minimum, replace `>` with `&gt;` and `<` with `&lt;`, but more precautions should be taken. Could you please tell us what language you are using in the server-side of things? PHP has `html_entities()`, but I'm not sure about other languages.

Comment: i dont want to escape html ,because user data can contain valid html