# Java replace all non-HTML Tags in a String

Tags: java, tags, html-parsing

I'd like to replace all the tag-looking parts in a String if those are not valid HTML tags.
A tag-looking part is something enclosed in `<>` brackets. Eg. `<myemail@email.com>` or `<hello>` but `<br>`, `<div>`, and so on has to be kept.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

cheers,

balázs

Comment: replace or remove? Please show expected output.

Comment: "one two three <blabla> four <text> five <div class="bold">six</div>" to "one two three four five <div class="bold">six</div>" - so replace to an empty String.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) to clean HTML.

```
String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

You can either use one of the defined [Whitelists](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) or you can create your own custom one in which you specify which HTML elements you wish to allow through the cleaner. Everything else is removed.

---

Your specific example would be:

```
String html = "one two three <blabla> four <text> five <div class=\"bold\">six</div>";
String cleaned = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed().addAttributes("div", "class"));
System.out.println(cleaned);
```

Output:

```
one two three  four  five 
<div class="bold">
 six
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the java.util.Scanner class - you can set a delimiter then see if the string matches HTML tag or not - you will have to build an Array of strings that should be ignored.

Comment: i did not want to build the Array by myself, i was rather looking for an already existing Enum, similar to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Tag.html

Comment: Something similar to this post then -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: yes, i've also seen that. so my problem is similar except that I don't wanna strip the HTML tags but keep them.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to include ending tags in your comparison algorithm. So you may want to look for a forward slash(html end tag) and strip it before your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in order to display untrusted data on the web page, simple removing of invalid tags is not enough. Take a look at [OWASP AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_AntiSamy_Project).

Comment: thanks for the hint, im gonna have a look at it, but this time i'd like them to remove simply. no more, no less.