# Remove all HTML tags except <br> from a text?

Tags: java, regex

hi all
I have a java string which I want to 
1- remove all html tags except the new line tags `<br>` and `</br>` from it and keep the text inside the tags if there's a text.
2- after parsing the text result is concatenated to each other like: text1andtext2 , there's no space separation between the texts, I want to do that too.

here's what I am doing:

```
String html = "<div dir=\"ltr\">hello my friend<span>ECHO</span><br>how are you ?<br><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\">On Mon, Feb 14, 2011 at 10:45 AM, My Friend <span dir=\"ltr\">&lt;<a href=\"mailto:notifications@mydomain.com\">notifications@mydomain.com</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br> "
            + "<blockquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0.8ex; border-left: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding-left: 1ex;\"> ";
    String parsedText = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
    System.out.println(parsedText);
```

current output:

```
hello my friendECHOhow are you ?On Mon, Feb 14, 2011 at 10:45 AM, My Friend &lt;notifications@mydomain.com&gt; wrote:
```

desired output:

```
hello my friend ECHO <br> how are you ? <br> <br> On Mon, Feb 14, 2011 at 10:45 AM, My Friend &`lt;notifications@mydomain.com&gt; wrote:`
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: nope I don't want to remove all html tags, coz that's actually what the code is doing, I want to remove all html tags except the new line tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
final String html =
    "<div dir=\"ltr\">hello my friend<span>ECHO</span><br>how are you ?" +
    "<br><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\">On Mon, Feb 14, 2011 at 10:45 AM," +
    " My Friend <span dir=\"ltr\">&lt;<a href=\"mailto:notifications@mydo" +
    "main.com\">notifications@mydomain.com</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br><bloc" +
    "kquote class=\"gmail_quote\" style=\"margin: 0pt 0pt 0pt 0.8ex; bord" +
    "er-left: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding-left: 1ex;\"> ";
final Pattern tagPattern = Pattern.compile("<([^\\s>/]+).*?>");
final Matcher matcher = tagPattern.matcher(html);
final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(html.length());
while(matcher.find()){
    matcher
        .appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("br")
            ? matcher.group()
            : " ");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);

final String parsedText = sb.toString();
System.out.println(parsedText);
```

**Output:**

```
hello my friendECHO<br>how are you ?<br><br>On Mon, Feb 14, 2011 at 10:45 AM,
My Friend &lt;notifications@mydomain.com&gt; wrote:<br>
```

But I hope you know that [Cthulhu is calling if you do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Don't parse HTML / XML with Regex!!

Comment: thanks a lot for the above example, but do you mean that i should do that with html parser like Jsoup ?

Comment: I mean that for a simple example like this one, Regex *might* be ok, but if it gets even a bit more complicated, yes, JSoup might be a good idea.

Comment: @Sean: "But I hope you know that Cthulhu is calling if you do." Entertaining reply :)

Comment: and what about that the text format hello my friendECHO there should be a space between them

Comment: @sword ok, then change the line to this: `matcher.group(1).equalsIgnoreCase("br") ? matcher.group() : " ");`

Comment: @James not my own idea, unfortunately: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Sean, one more thing, this pattern doesn't catch the <br/>

Comment: @sword use this one: `"</?([^\\s>/]+).*?>"`

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for the reference. @sword: An alternative would be to use JDOM with some checks turned off. I managed to do this a while ago to extract some text but it was a pain getting it working and I can't seem to find the source.

Answer (score 3):

I would

- replace all <br/> with newline or another special character.
- remove all tags.
- replace the special character with <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Question

[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text/6031463#6031463)