# Java/Parsing: how to replace & symbol but not html codes

Tags: java, parsing

I need to replace all "`&`" symbols with "`&#38`" in my text file but not the html codes such as `&amp;` or `&quot;`

I'm currently using `row = row.replace("& ", "&#38");`

but, as I said also the html codes are replaced e.g. `&quot;` and I don't want this..
thanks

ps. I cannot add spaces after & because I need to replace it in words such as `M&M` or `Ella & David`

Comment: You need a semicolon too. `&#38;` or `&amp;`, not just `&#38`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a regex, e.g,

```
row = row.replaceAll("&(?![#a-zA-Z0-9]+;)", "&#38;");
```

The regex replace `&` given that it's *not* followed by `a sequence of '#a-zA-Z0-9' ending with ';'`

Comment: sorry, there was an error in my question. The html codes do not have # after the &, but they have few letters (different lenght) ending with a ;

Comment: Your regex doesn't work for `&#333;` form of strings. What you probably need is `row.replaceAll("&(?![#a-zA-Z0-9]+;)", "&#38;");`

Comment: @adarshr, that wasn't clear from the question, but in all fairness, you are completely right! I'll update accordingly, thx.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general solution, since in your text there may be things like

```
&amp;
```

which may mean either a single ampersand or be a malformed way of saying `&amp;` which should be expressed as

```
&amp;amp;
```

However, the latter is quite improbable (unless you're escaping some HTML).

So try something like

```
row = row.replaceAll("&(?!(?:\\#|amp|quot|nbsp|\\d+);)", "&amp;");
```

Btw., `&#38` is missing the final semicolon. Prefer `&amp;` to using ASCII codes.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `"& "` should be `"&\\s"`, since whitespace has a pattern identifier too.

So the line should read `row = row.replace("&\\s", "&#38");`

Comment: except I just noticed your postscript, so this wouldn't catch the `&` in `M&M`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String replacedAmpersands = row.replaceAll("&(?!(?:#\\d+|\\p{L}+);)", "&#38;")
```

This will only replace ampersands that are not followed by `#\d+;` (hash, numbers, semicolon) or `\p{L}+;` (letters, semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more involved but my feeling is that it is fullproof, whereas the regex solutions may not be 100% correct (as per the famous ["do not use regex for HTML stackoverflow thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).

Using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org):

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

This will give you for sure a text only containing the ampersands you need, not the rest.

Then create a Map containing on the left-hand side the phrases like `M&M` and `Ella & David` and then on the right hand side the phrases `M&amp;M` and `Ella &amp; David`

The final step is going back to the initial HTML text and replacing the strings on the LHS of the map with those of the RHS.

Edit: you can of course use any HTML parser you like - just wanted to give you a quick example of how easy it is to use one.