# Is there a function that converts HTML to plaintext?

Tags: java, android, html

Is there a "hocus-pocus" function, suitable for Android, that converts HTML to plaintext?

I am referring to a function like the clipboard conversion operation found in browsers like Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc: If you select all rendered HTML inside the browser and copy/paste it to a text editor, you will receive (most of) the text, without any HTML tags or headers.

In a similar thread, I saw a reference to [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) but it's in Python. I am looking for an  Android/Java function.

Is there something like this available or must I do this myself, using Jsoup or Jtidy?

Comment: Use this it Works :)
--------------------------------------- http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Convert_HTML_to_plain_text It does the mime conversion from text/html to text/plain.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd try something like:

```
String html = "<b>hola</b>";
String plain = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, it removes the HTML tags but it still contains all the response headers and javascript code in the page... I am looking for the "clipboard text" function I described above.

Comment: That's not something available in the API. It's a private implementation of the web browser... you may take a look at its source code to see how it's implemented.

Comment: How about Jsoup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: Nice one dude... I haven't heard of it.

Comment: It turns out Html class itself uses a flavor of Jsoup, called TagSoup.

Comment: The `HTML` class is `android.text.Html` right? (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6385950/694469 )

Answer (score 0):

**Using JSOUP :**

```
String plain = new HtmlToPlainText().getPlainText(Jsoup.parse(html));
```

**Without JSOUP:**

```
String html= "htmltext";
String newHtml = html.replaceAll("(?s)<[^>]*>(\\s*<[^>]*>)*", " ").trim();
```