# Extract data from html code with Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to extract from this HTML code the word `Mustafa` with Jsoup.

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Mustafa</h1>
        <!-- /firstHeading -->
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 2):

With [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) you can use [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to select elements. An element with `id="firstHeading"` is selectable with CSS selector `#firstHeading`.

Thus, this should do:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String firstHeading = document.select("#firstHeading").text();
System.out.println(firstHeading); // Mustafa
```