# Problems in Database Management - sqlite with Java (IDE: NetBeans)

Tags: java, sqlite

I have some problems in managing the storage of data via query (NetBeans-> Java-> Sqlite):

- 1) I have a folder with some txt file, containing several lines of text (the files do not exceed   2 Kb)
- 2) The program opens the files in sequence, and stores each word in a table
- 3)When the program comes to analyze too much data (some time more than 40 files ore more then 82) returns the following error

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: unable to open database file
         at org.sqlite.DB.throwex (DB.java: 288)
         at org.sqlite.DB.executeBatch (DB.java: 236)
         at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.executeBatch (PrepStmt.java: 83)

- The error is in  int [] upCountsb = prepb.executeBatch();

---

### Here the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;



public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/.../test.db");
                Statement stmt;
                stmt = conn.createStatement();

                stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words");
                stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE words (words)");


String path_dir ="C:/Users/.../good";
File currentDIR = new File("C:/Users/.../good");
File files[]=currentDIR.listFiles();
String tmp="";

ArrayList app = new ArrayList();

//Search in DIR for Files
for( File f1 : files ){
        String nameFile = f1.getName();

        FileReader f = null;
        BufferedReader fIN = null;
        String s;

       //Open the file xxx.txt
        try{

         f = new FileReader(path_dir+"/"+nameFile);
         fIN = new BufferedReader(f);
         s = fIN.readLine();

           while(s != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {


                    String str = st.nextToken().toString().toLowerCase();
                    Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("\\W", Pattern.MULTILINE); 
                    String newAll = pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll("").trim();
                    tmp=newAll;


             app.add(tmp); //Add all data in the ArrayList app

                 } // Close  While 'hasMoreTokens'

                s = fIN.readLine();
           } //Close While on File


    } //Close TRAY
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
 f.close(); //Close FileReader
 } //Close Scan DIR for FILE


//Add all data in the Tbl od Database
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into words values (?);");
for (int z=0; z<app.size();z++){


                    prep.setString(1,app.get(z).toString().toLowerCase());
                    prep.addBatch();

                   conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  prep.executeBatch();   ***//Here I get the error although i use int [] Count =prep.executeBatch();***
                   conn.setAutoCommit(true);


                    }
            prep.close();

            } //Close MAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to release the resources you are using once you are done with them. E.g. `prepb.close()` after executing the statement.

The same thing goes for your file handles.

Also, the point of batching is lost if you execute the statement for every insert.

Since your files are very small you might as well prepare all the data in memory before you persist it to a database.

```
package stackoverflow.wordanalysis;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class WordFrequencyImporter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> words = readWords("the-directory-from-which-to-read-the-files");
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        try {
            createWordsTable(conn);
            persistWords(words, conn);
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    private static void persistWords(List<String> words, Connection conn)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Persisting " + words.size() + " words");
        PreparedStatement prep = conn
                .prepareStatement("insert into words values (?);");
        try {
            for (String word : words) {
                prep.setString(1, word);
                prep.addBatch();

            }
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            prep.executeBatch();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

        } finally {
            prep.close();

        }
    }

    private static void createWordsTable(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS words");
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE words (words)");
        } finally {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> readWords(String path_dir) throws IOException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File file : new File(path_dir).listFiles()) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            System.out.println("Reading " + file);
            try {
                String s;
                while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String token = st.nextToken().toString().toLowerCase();
                        String word = pattern.matcher(token).replaceAll("")
                                .trim();
                        words.add(word);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I'm testing your solution ... give me a moment

Comment: Hello,
I analyzed and tested your solution but still receive the same error.
to follow the modified code:

Comment: Please show us all the code, including the part where you initialize `conn`.

Comment: Hi!, I have modify the code in the question box,  now you can see the inizialization of conn.

Comment: I've added an example that deals with the resources in a proper way and does not execute the prepared statement more than once. It's been tested on about 200 files having a total of 887888 words. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi!
Thanks! your advice worked! 
I converted your code to a second variant , basically i did not released the resources after executing them, I mean  the database try{…} finally{…} prep.close(); and as you showed, I minimized the disk access

Another thing, how can I  perfect the code, so that when I read a file I discard certain set of string for example  { <html> <tr> <td> http ... <table>  } and so on

Comment: Glad to help. Regarding your other issue, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: Hello, I wrote a new question, which relates (+ -) to the same problem seen here, if you have time.., you can find it at this link ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737499/map-problem-with-java-and-sqlite-database

Comment: I may find time to look into it. Btw, since this question is done you should mark it as so.