# MAP Problem with JAVA and Sqlite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, dictionary

I have another question for you:
The code below does the following

1. For each file in a folder
2. Open the file and read its    contents
3. Take and divide each line into    tokens
4. Save each token (word) in a hasMap
5. Prepare a database query (Select    form words ...)
6. For each match found between the tokens and the words contained in the database Write 1.0, if true, otherwise 0.0;

**The problem arises at this point**:

```
try{
    while (rs_mail.next()) {
        if(result_m.contains(rs_mail.getString("voc_w").toString()))  //HERE I GET THE ERROR! java.lang.NullPointerException
            out_final.print("1.0;"); 
        else
            out_final.print("0.0;"); 
    }//Close While
}       //Close TRY
finally{
    rs_mail.close();
    //result_m.clear();
    mail.clear(); //Clear MAP
}
```

**Below the complete code**:

```
String path ="C:/Users/.../file";
File currentDIR = new File("C:/Users/.../file");
File files_mail[]=currentDIR.listFiles();
String tmp_mail="";

// prepares the file tmpTraning.txt to receive value 1.0, 0.0 obtained by comparison with database
PrintWriter out_final=null;
File ff=new File("C:/Users/.../tmpTraning.txt");

//Seach for File in DIR
for( File fX : files_mail ){
    String name_Filex = fX.getName();
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader fINx = null;
    String sx;
    //Create MAP 
    Map<String, Set<String>> mail = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    //Open File
    try{
        Set<String> sq = new HashSet<String>();

        fr = new FileReader(path+"/"+name_Filex);
        fINx = new BufferedReader(fr);
        sx = fINx.readLine();

        //scroll the file
        while(sx != null) {
            StringTokenizer stq = new StringTokenizer(sx);
            while(stq.hasMoreTokens()) { //Extract form line the single word
                tmp_mail = stq.nextToken();

                sq.add(tmp_mail.toString().toLowerCase()); //add the word to sq -> HashMap
                mail.put(nome_Filex, sq);

            }// Close st.hasMoreTokens()

            sx = fINx.readLine();
        } //Close  while for scroll File
        fr.close(); //Close fileReader
        sq.clear(); //Clear HasSet

    } //Close il TRAY
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Set<String> result_m = mail.get(name_Filex);
    ResultSet rs_mail = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT voc.words as voc_w FROM voc_words as voc");

    //Prepare for writing on the file " tmpTraning.txt " 
    OutputStreamWriter fout_f = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(ff,true));
    out_final = new PrintWriter(fout_f);

    try{
        while (rs_mail.next()) {
            //If the word extract from the database is in MAP (name_Filex) then print 1.0; on the file tmpTraning.txt
            if(result_m.contains(rs_mail.getString("voc_w").toString()))  //HERE I GET THE ERROR! java.lang.NullPointerException
                out_final.print("1.0;"); 
            else
                //else print 0.0;
                out_final.print("0.0;"); 
        }
    }       //Close TRY
    finally{
        rs_mail.close();
        //result_m.clear();
        mail.clear(); //Clear MAP
    }

    out_final.println(""); //Send CR char ASCII to set the coursor for the next file on the new line
    out_final.close();
    out_final.flush();
} // End SCAN DIR
```

***Thanks for any advice!***

**Code changes - print the contents of result_m**:

```
String path ="...";
File currentDIR = new File("...");
File files_mail[]=currentDIR.listFiles();
String tmp_mail="";

// prepares the file tmpTraning.txt to receive value 1.0, 0.0 obtained by comparison with database
PrintWriter out_final=null;
File ff=new File("...");

//Seach for File in DIR
for( File fX : currentDIR.listFiles() ){
    String name_Filex = fX.getName();

    String sx;
    //Create MAP 
    Map<String, Set<String>> mail = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    //Open File
    try{
        Set<String> sq = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader fINx = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fX));
        sx = fINx.readLine();
        //scroll the file
        while(sx != null) {
            StringTokenizer stq = new StringTokenizer(sx);
            while(stq.hasMoreTokens()) { //Extract form line the single word
                tmp_mail = stq.nextToken();

                sq.add(tmp_mail.toString().toLowerCase()); //add the word to sq -> HashMap
                mail.put(name_Filex, sq);

            }// Close st.hasMoreTokens()

            sx = fINx.readLine();
        } //Close  while for scroll File
        fr.close(); //Close fileReader
        sq.clear(); //Clear HasSet

    } //Close il TRAY
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
     * print the contents of  result_m
     */

    System.out.println("----- START FILE -----");
    Set<String> result_m = mail.get(name_Filex);
    Object[] toArray_m = mail.get(name_Filex).toArray();
    for (int ncc=0; ncc<result_m.size();ncc++){
        System.out.println(toArray_m[ncc]);
    }
    System.out.println("----- END  FILE  -----");


} // End SCAN DIR
```

*if the file read by the program contains blank lines (no char, no string), it saves a null value*

Comment: You don't have a debugger? check if one of (or both!) `result_m` or `rs_mail.getString("voc_w")` is null.

Comment: Is there any reason that `mail.put(nome_Filex, sq);` is using `nome_Filex` rather than `name_Filex`? If you have a `nome_Filex` hiding somewhere, then this is probably why `mail.get(name_Filex)` would return `null` (making `result_m` to be `null`).

Comment: Is a typo.
I have not copied the code directly from the IDE, sorry, my fault

Comment: Seems like `SELECT DISTINCT voc.words as voc_w FROM voc_words` should have been `SELECT DISTINCT words as voc_w FROM voc_words`. At least `voc` is not defined.

Comment: I retested the code, I noticed that some files that are read are empty (for EXAMPLE: The file has two lines, but these are empty, no char or string to read) This seems to cause the error, comparing a word in the database with a null value returns an error - of course - So I wonder, how can I avoid writing in the HashMap if the file is empty (there are more lines but there are not strings of characters / words) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason that you are calling `toString()` on a string? If `getString("voc_w")` is `null`, then it will cause your exception.

As manji pointed out in the comment, it's either the call I mentioned, or the `result_m` `Set` that are `null`.

Comment: I added a System.out.println after result_m
It print some values ​​properly, after which it returns null, but I do not understand why.
By the way, I removed the toString (); from getString, but the error appears again

Comment: I retested the code, I noticed that some files that are read are empty (for EXAMPLE: The file has two lines, but these are empty, no char or string to read) This seems to cause the error, comparing a word in the database with a null value returns an error - of course - So I wonder, how can I avoid writing in the HashMap if the file is empty (there are more lines but there are not strings of characters / words) ?

Comment: As you extract data from the files, do not add blanks. `String string = ...readFromFile...; if ( ! string.isEmpty()) { sq.add(string); }`

Answer (score 0):

There are a great many issues with your code, unfortunately. Here's *one* that springs to my eye immediately.

You are using string manipulation to create the filename that you are passing in to the `FileReader` constructor, despite the fact that as far as I can see the file being opened is one returned from a listing of the directory. That's just asking for trouble. Instead, the code would be better off written more like this...

```
// Lots of things are omitted; this is just a sketch...
String path = "...";
File currentDIR = new File(path);
for (File fX : currentDIR.listFiles()) {
    try {
        BufferedReader fINx = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fX));
        // ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printErrorStack();
    }
}
```

However, you have more problems than that. For example, the use of `sq.clear()` has bad code smell. You've just stowed a reference to that `Set` in the `Map`; why are you deleting its contents again? The variable is falling out of scope; you can simply leave that code out. The down-stream consequences of that `clear()` are that `result_m` later on will be an empty set, so its `contains` test will always return false. I can't tell offhand whether that's the cause of your rogue null, but *it's got to be wrong* on the basis of what you're claiming to want to do.

Try refactoring that code into several smaller pieces that are easier to verify correct. I suggest as a first cut: a private method to get the Set of words from a File (supplied as argument), a private method to compare a Set of words against the database, and a method that combines those two with some looping to achieve your overall goal.

Comment: I proceed with the rewriting of the code, and the division into small pieces

Comment: I retested the code, I noticed that some files that are read are empty (for EXAMPLE: The file has two lines, but these are empty, no char or string to read)
This seems to cause the error, comparing a word in the database with a null value returns an error - of course -
So I wonder, how can I avoid writing in the HashMap if the file is empty (there are more lines but there are not strings of characters / words) ?