# Reliable Parsing for RSS/XML feed in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

I am using XMLPULLPARSER in android. I am able to get all the information I want from multiple feeds. The issue is figuring out how to reliable get the descriptions parsed from the feeds.
The description tag from two of the feeds is as follows:

`**The "malnourished" singer says her mom is trying to help her eat better**<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/people/headlines/~4/of8YOoAtLaA" height="1" width="1"/>'

AND

'<img src="http://images.eonline.com/resize/66/66/eol_images/Entire_Site/2011515//300.garfield.lc.061511.jpg" height="66" width="66" border="0" alt="Andrew Gardield, Garrett Hedlund, Kate Mara" align="left" hspace="5" />**After the huge hullabaloo he caused by hitting the town with his On the Road costar Kristen Stewart, cutie-pie Garrett Hedlund apparently decided to keep a low profile in Hawaii with a less**...<br clear="all" />
<p><a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/kAgHF8uSo-kBC708djx7vWq7S5Y/0/da"><img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/kAgHF8uSo-kBC708djx7vWq7S5Y/0/di" border="0" ismap="true"></img></a><br/><a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/kAgHF8uSo-kBC708djx7vWq7S5Y/1/da"><img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/kAgHF8uSo-kBC708djx7vWq7S5Y/1/di" border="0" ismap="true"></img></a></p><div class="feedflare"><a href="http://feeds.eonline.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?a=oSTZWu5LPBA:XlROC-V1kVA:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.eonline.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?a=oSTZWu5LPBA:XlROC-V1kVA:7Q72WNTAKBA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.eonline.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?a=oSTZWu5LPBA:XlROC-V1kVA:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?i=oSTZWu5LPBA:XlROC-V1kVA:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://feeds.eonline.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?a=oSTZWu5LPBA:XlROC-V1kVA:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/eonline/topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></img></a></div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/eonline/topstories/~4/oSTZWu5LPBA" height="1" width="1"/>'

As you can see both are quite different. I have made the information that I want is bolded. There is no CDATA in the description so that option is not viable. I can parse the information I want out of each of them, but I would like an option that works for almost all situation. I am not sure that this is possible, but I have seen a number of RSS readers, podcast readers, that have managed to do third relatively successfully. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's html embedded in the description, to show it correctly you could use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

If you really just want to get the text description, you should look at the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string).