# Remove div tag from string

Tags: java, string

I have a string as follows:

```
This is a sample <b>String</b> I want to <div style="font-size:22px"> replace it fast </div>
```

How can I remove `<div>` start and `</div>` end tag from the above string in Java in one go?

Comment: Do you want to remove the `<div style="font-size:22px">` and the `</div>`?  Or all html tags?  Will the `<div style="font-size:22px">` always have the same style applied?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string ?

Comment: @nfechner i agree, you can find a suitable answer there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```
String s = "This is a sample <b>String</b> I want to <div style=\"font-size:22px\"> replace it fast </div>";
s = s.replaceAll("[<](/)?div[^>]*[>]", "");
```

This will result in:

```
This is a sample <b>String</b> I want to  replace it fast
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
myString.replaceAll("<div .*>(.*)</div>","$1");
```

btw: there is a online regular expression tester for java:

http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

(if you did not know it)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Which do you want?

```
String s = "This is a sample <b>String</b> I want to <div style=\"font-size:22px\"> replace it fast </div>";

// if you want to remove only div tag.
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("</?div[^>]*?>", ""));
// if you want to remove tag include text.
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<div[^>]*?>.*?</div[^>]*?>", ""));
// language: java
```