# Java remove Sub-string that includes quotes

Tags: java, string, replace, quotes

```
    String strLine = "";

    try
    {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("html.txt"));
        strLine = b.readLine();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    String[] temp = strLine.split("<");
    temp = temp[1].split(">");
    String temp1 = ("<"+temp[0]+">");

    strLine = strLine.replaceFirst(temp1,"");
    System.out.println(strLine);
```

Basically I want to remove this string

```
<span title="Representation in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)" class="IPA">
```

from from the file that contains

```
<span title="Representation in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA)" class="IPA">no'b?l</span>
```

However so far my code works only if the string contains no quotes. How can I fix this problem. I have tried using

```
.replaceAll("\\\"","\\\\\"");
```

but still failed.

Any help or info will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: Yes well that's what I want eventually and this code works fine without quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string. It's really simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that replaceFirst accepts a regular expression, but you're feeding it an arbitrary string, that might contain all sorts of special characters that have a specific meaning in a regular expression. I don't think the quotes are your problem, but rather the <strike>question mark</strike> parentheses.

One way to work around this is to use the [String#replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, which accepts a string rather than a regular expression. That is, use the following line:

```
strLine = strLine.replace(temp1,"");
```

This differs from your code in that it replaces all the instances of temp1 in that line, and not just the first one, but I think you should be fine with that.

Comment: Yes thankyou, changing the strLine.replaceAll to strLine.replace fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `replaceAll("///"","/////"");` would work if you escaped correctly: the escape character is `\`, not `/`. Try using that instead.

Comment: temp1 = temp1.replaceAll("\\\"","\\\\\""); I tried this however It still doesn't work. Maybe its not because of the quotes.