# Removing Html tags except few specific ones from String in java

Tags: java, html

My input is plain text string and requirement is to remove all html tags except few specific tags like:

```
<p>
<li>
<u>
<li>
```

If these specific tags have attributes like `class` or `id`, I want to remove these attributes.

A few examples:

```
<a href = "#">Link</a>            ->   Link

<p>paragraph</p>                  ->   <p>paragraph</p>

<p class="class1">paragraph</p>   ->   <p>paragraph</p>
```

I have gone through this [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string) but it does not answer my question completely.

Can it be handled by a set of regex's or could I make use of some library?

Comment: How constrained is your HTML input? If it's arbitrary (X)HTML, then regular expressions alone may [not be enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Things like CDATA blocks, comments and script elements can throw simplistic regex off.

Comment: Yes, It may contain these CDATA blocks and javascript. I am ready to make use of some library. But just wondering, how would any library distinguish between javascript code and plain text in a String.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried JSoup and It seems to be able to handle all such cases. Here is example code.

```
 public String clean(String unsafe){
        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
        whitelist.addTags(new String[]{"p","br","ul"});

        String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, whitelist);
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(safe);
 }
```

For input string

```
String unsafe = "<p class='p1'>paragraph</p>< this is not html > <a link='#'>Link</a> <![CDATA[<sender>John Smith</sender>]]>";
```

I get following output which is pretty much I require.

```
<p>paragraph</p>< this is not html > Link <sender>John Smith</sender>
```

Comment: What if we want to compulsorily have an attribute also like tag <a> and <href> attribute as compulsory

Answer (score 4):

For simple HTML, this may be sufficient:

```
// remove any <script> tags
html = html.replaceAll("(?i)<script.*?</script>", ""));
// this removes any attributes
html = html.replaceAll("(?i)<([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)(\\s[^>]*)>", "<$1>"));
// this removes any tags (not li and p)
html = html.replaceAll("(?i)<(?!(/?(li|p)))[^>]*>", ""));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks beny.. yes it's working fine for simple html but I tried Jsoup. It seems to be able to handle all these cases pretty well.

Comment: would add my answer after time limit to answer your own question is over.

Comment: For anyone reading this answer: it's a really bad idea to manipulate a complex-grammar language like HTML with regexes. As proof: try the above code on `<lihellø onLoad="alert('hi')">Hello</lihellø>` and see that it doesn't work. You can fix the regex but then someone will find another way around. See also the famous answer on: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)