# Manipulate html document

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup, html-manipulation

```
...<b><a>hello</a></b>...
```

I'd like to remove the `<b></b>` tags from the html document. Is it possible using Jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `doc` is your Document containig your HTML:

```
doc.select("b").unwrap();
```

(can be used with `Element` / `Elements` too)

**Example:**

```
Document document = new Document("");
document.html("...<b><a>hello</a></b>...").select("b").unwrap();
```

Now your document doesn't contain any b-Tag

Answer (score 0):

```
public String clean(String unsafe){ 
        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none(); 
        whitelist.addTags(new String[]{"a"}); 

        String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, whitelist); 
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(safe); 
 }
```

From [Removing Html tags except few specific ones from String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023994/removing-html-tags-except-few-specific-ones-from-string-in-java)