# Send combined plain text/HTML mail with Spring and JavaMail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, mime

I'm currently using JavaMail and Spring to send email in HTML. As it happens, the HTML is generated by some Velocity templates I have, and the sending code is roughly as follows:

```
MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

    @Override public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");

            message.setSubject(msgInfo.getSubject());
            message.setFrom(msgInfo.getFrom());
            message.setReplyTo(msgInfo.getFrom());
            message.setTo(address);
            message.setText(someText, true);
    }
}

mailSender.send(preparator);
```

This works just fine, but it sends the mail with only a single part as `text/html`. What I need is to send it in multipart alternative with a plain text part. Is there  a way, using Spring and JavaMail, to do this in an automatic way?

---

### P.S.

In a former life when I programmed with Visual Basic and [CDONTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration_Data_Objects_for_Windows_NT_Server) this was built-in, but I can't seem to find a simple way to do it with Java. It's not terribly important that the plain text version look good, it just has to exist. What I'm trying to avoid is having to maintain a whole second set of Velocity templates just for this.

Comment: Strip out the HTML? Without knowing much about what your HTML mail contains it's hard to be super-constructive. There's nothing automatic, though. Personally, I switched to using Markdown-like syntax for the text email, and transforming it to HTML. Easier, if you don't need fancy HTML. Otherwise you're probably stuck.

Comment: Hm...the HTML is nothing fancy, just a few `<p>`s and maybe a `<ul>` here and there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to send both Text and HTML parts, you need to use a different `setText()` method:

> [`public void setText(String plainText, String htmlText)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

If you are setting the *plain text* to your HTML content, you may need to parse the HTML to remove the HTML tags.

Comment: I see. It still seems odd that CDONTS had this 13 years ago and JavaMail doesn't today, but I suppose they're different platforms with different design approaches. Oh well.

Comment: Just found a post for stripping HTML from your string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    // Email data
    String Email_Id = "samarthaniket16@gmail.com"; // change to your
                                                    // email ID
    String password = "Your PSWD"; // change to your password
    String recipient_mail_id = "samarthaniket16@gmail.com"; // change to
                                                            // recipient
                                                            // email id
    String mail_subject = "Attendance Report";

    // Set mail properties
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    String host_name = "smtp.gmail.com";
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host_name);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", Email_Id);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        // Set email data
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Email_Id));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient_mail_id));
        message.setSubject(mail_subject);
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Set key values
        Map<String, String> input = new HashMap<String, String>();
        input.put("User", name.toString());
        input.put("Date", date1);
        input.put("Content In", "English");
        input.put("Absent", absentUser);

        // HTML mail content
        // String htmlText =
        // readEmailFromHtml("/home/techwalnut-pc/mailTemplate.html",
        // input);
        String htmlText = readEmailFromHtml(
                "/home/techwalnut-pc/Development/Aniket/Techwalnut/Project/Java/Spring/Attendance_system/mailTemplate.html",
                input);
        messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Conect to smtp server and send Email
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host_name, Email_Id, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Mail sent successfully...");

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
    } catch (Exception ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
   exception.printStackTrace();
}
```