# removing html tags using a for loop in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing HTML from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

I am having a problem removing htmls tags from a text file in java. I know it would be easy to use something like

```
str=str.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

However I want to know if I could split the string and go throught and replace everything srarting from < to > with "".

I tried

```
String [] str= "<tag>with some string </tag>";
String  s="";
    for (i=0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i].toString()=="<")
        {
            str[i]="";
        }
        else if (str[i].toString()==">")
        {
            s=s+str[i+1];
        }
    }
```

when i try printing the new string s, it just prints out with just white space. 
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to some flag variable denoting you are inside of tag and add the third situation when you are not in the tag, so the rest of content gets added to string. For example:

```
String [] str= "<tag>with some string </tag>";
String  s="";
boolean inTag = false;
for (i=0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    if (str[i].toString()=="<")
    {
        inTag = true;
    }
    else if (str[i].toString()==">")
    {
        inTag = false;
    }else{
        if (!inTag)
            s = s + str[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied have a few errors. But anyway, you may do it with [`String#Split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] strArr = str.split("\\<.*?>");
```

This will eliminate the tags.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the html tags from a text file just look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string) topic previously discussed in this forum