# Reading data from a text file, a badly written text file

Tags: java, file, parsing, variables, text

I'm writing a program that takes data from rows in a text file. the problem is that its not the best written text file and there is much confusion when trying to write a parser for the file

Here are two such rows, for both I can get the address and latitude and longitude variables but on the second one i cannot get price or size(s). the error i keep getting is a string out of bounds exception of -41 (seriously)

```
|12091805|,|0|,|DETAILS|,||,||,|Latitude:54.593406, Longitude:-5.934344 <b >Unit 8 Great Northern Mall Great Victoria Street Belfast Down<//b><p><p><p>Price : 150,000<p>Size: 2,411 Sq Feet  ()<p>Rent : 50,500 Per Annum<p><p>Text<p><p>|,||,||

|15961081|,|0|,|DETAILS|,||,||,|<p>Latitude:54.593406, Longitude:-5.934344   <b>3-5 Market Street Lurgan BT66</b> </p>  <p> </p>  <p> </p>  <p>   Price : &pound;250,000 </p>  <p>   Size: 0.173 acres (0.07ha) </p>  <p> </p>  <p>   Text </p>  <p> </p>  <p>  Text </p>  <p> </p>  <p>   Text </p>  <p> </p>  <p> </p>|,||,||
```

Its a lot longer but I changed the paragraphs just to say text for now.

And no, I cannot re-write the text file. Any pointers would be appreciated

```
if (s.contains("Price"))
{
    int pstart = 0;
    int pend = 0;

    if (s.contains("<p>Size"))
    {

        //if has pound symbol
        if (s.contains("&pound;"))
        {
            String[] str = s.split("&pound;");
            StringBuilder bs = new StringBuilder();
            for (String st : str)
            {
                bs.append(st);
            }

            pstart = bs.indexOf("Price") + 8;
            pend = bs.indexOf("</p>") - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pstart = s.indexOf("Price") + 8;
            pend = s.indexOf("<p>Size");
        }

        String sp = s.substring(pstart, pend);

        String[] spl = sp.split(",");
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        for (String st : spl)
        {
            build.append(st);
            f = build.toString();
        }
        in = Integer.parseInt(f);
        p.setPrice(in);
    }
    else
    {
        if (s.contains("&pound;"))
        {
            String[] str = s.split("&pound;");
            StringBuilder bs = new StringBuilder();
            for (String st : str)
            {
                bs.append(st);
            }

            pstart = bs.indexOf("Price : ");
            pend = bs.indexOf("</p>") - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            pstart = s.indexOf("Price") + 8;
            pend = s.indexOf("<p>Size");
        }

        String sp = s.substring(pstart, pend);

        String[] spl = sp.split(",");
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        for (String st : spl)
        {
            build.append(st);
            f = build.toString();
        }
        in = Integer.parseInt(f);
        p.setPrice(in);
    }
}

// if has size property
if (s.contains("Size"))
{
    //if in acres
    if (s.contains("acres"))
    {
        int sstart = s.indexOf("Size:") + 6;
        int send = s.indexOf("acres") - 1;

        String sp = s.substring(sstart, send);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(sp);

        p.setSized(d);

    }

    if (s.contains("()"))
    {
        int sstart = s.indexOf("Size:") + 6;

        int send = s.indexOf("Sq") - 2;

        String sp = s.substring(sstart, send);

        if (sp.contains("-") && sp.contains(","))
        {
            String[] spl = sp.split("-|,");

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(spl[0] + spl[1]);

            StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder(0);
            str2.append(spl[2] + spl[3]);

            String s1 = str.toString();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s1);
            p.setSize(i);

            String s2 = str2.toString();
            i = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            p.setSize2(i);
        }

        if (sp.contains("-"))
        {
            String[] spl = sp.split("-");

            int one = Integer.parseInt(spl[0]);

            p.setSize(one);

            int two = Integer.parseInt(spl[1]);

            p.setSize2(two);

        }
        else if (!(sp.contains("-")))
        {
            if (sp.contains(","))
            {
                String[] spl = sp.split(",");
                StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
                for (String st : spl)
                {
                    build.append(st);
                    f = build.toString();
                }
                in = Integer.parseInt(f);
                p.setSize(in);
            }
            else
            {
                p.setSize(Integer.parseInt(sp));
            }

        }

    }

}
v.add(p);
p = new Property();
```

Comment: it would help if you show us an example of how the file looks like

Comment: is it text file or html file?

Comment: sorry about that, added in the row data

Comment: how big is the file? if it's not big just replace the tags <p> <b>... with normal splitters either coma or a pipe or whatever. use sed to do so. and you will save yourself lots of time instead of wasting it.

Comment: ...... replace the tags with commas with sed or replace() and use your .split() there be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regular expressions, the following should point you in the right direction:

```
Pattern pricePattern = Pattern.compile("Price\\s*:\\s*(&pound;)?([0-9,.]+)"); 
Pattern sqFeetPattern = Pattern.compile("Size\\s*:\\s*([0-9,.]+)\\s*Sq"); 
Pattern acresPattern = Pattern.compile("Size\\s*:\\s*([0-9,.]+)\\s*acres\\s*\\(([0-9,.]+)ha\\)"); 

NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(true);

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = pricePattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        int price = nf.parse(m.group(2)).intValue();
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
    }
    m = sqFeetPattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        int sqFeet = nf.parse(m.group(1)).intValue();
        System.out.println("Sq Feet: " + sqFeet);
    }
    m = acresPattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        float acres = nf.parse(m.group(1)).floatValue();
        float ha = nf.parse(m.group(2)).floatValue();
        System.out.println("Acres: " + acres + " ha: " + ha);
    }
}
```

N.B. `inputFileReader` would be defined as a `FileReader` or similar to get your file.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is.

1. Read the line of text
2. Decode the line of text - looks like HTML markup, so convert escaped characters (`&pound;` for example) to the equivalent text character and filter out HTML markup (`<p>` etc)
3. Perform extraction of data on the cleaned up data using Regular Expressions
4. Process data
5. Next line or end.

For step 2, something like this is what I'm thinking. So you strip all of the html markup out of the string before splitting it on the field separater (|)

[Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

Comment: Thats what Ive been doing but if you look at the rows, you see that the price number in one row is followed by a different element than it was in the other row.

Comment: replace Price : &pound; to Price : everywhere

Comment: Thats the problem though, I cant change the text file at all the one I will have to use at a later is the exact same thing but in an external database so I cant change it now, get it to work and call it done, doesnt work like that.

Comment: I don't mean to change the text file. This can all be done on each string as you read it in. See updated answer for more explanation of step 2.