# removing all "<...>" from a java String

Tags: java, string, tags

I have a string and i'd like to remove all tags with < and >

For example:

in the String

```
<title>Java Code</title>
```

will be

```
Java Code
```

and

```
<pre><font size="7"><strong>Some text here

</strong></font><strong>
```

will be

```
Some text here
```

How can it be done with using charAt(i)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use regular expressions?

Comment: @AnotherCode   I have text with also full with < > tags, I wanna remove them all and only see the text.

Comment: You can find similar post, it will help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: If you are trying to parse html than I suggest you better use `html parser` for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can it be done with using charAt(i)?

Here is how:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "<pre><font size=\"7\"><strong>Some text here\n\n</strong></font><strong>";

    String o = "";
    boolean append = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '<')
            append = false;

        if (append)
            o += s.charAt(i);

        if (s.charAt(i) == '>')
            append = true;
    }

    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple to do this using regular expressions.

```
String src = "<title>Java Code</title>";
String dst = src.replaceAll("<.+?>", "");

System.out.println(dst);
```

Comment: He wanted to use `charAt`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically want to use chatAt(i), here is the algorithm,

- Start traversing the string from the beginning.
- If the character you encounter is an opening tag(<), start traversing the string until you find the closing tag (>). then check the next character, If it is (< ) , then repeat the same process again.
- If the next character is not (<), Then start printing the string until you see another (<).
- Then repeat step 2.

Answer (score 0):

with `charAt`, you could loop over all the characters in you string, removing everything from < until the next >. However, your string could contain non-ASCII UTF code points, which could break this approach.

I would go with a regex, something like

```
String someTextHere = "...";
String cleanedText = someTextHere.replaceAll( "<[^>]*?>", "" );
```

However, let me also point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), which lists concerns with the regex approach.