# Removing html tags in from a string in android

Tags: android, html, string, tags

I have a string which has html tags. I want to remove the html tags completely. How can I achieve this?
The string goes something like this

```
<messageContent><p><a href="http://www.business-standard.com/india/news/markets-trade-flatpositive-bias/159747/on" target="_blank"><strong>Markets trade flat with positive bias</strong></a><br />
<a href="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/local-markets/nifty-choppy-icici-bank-infosys-wipro-gain_677519.html" target="_blank"><strong>Nifty choppy; ICICI Bank, Infosys, Wipro gain</strong></a><br />
BSE 17127.09 (-46.20)<br />
NSE 5208.15 (-14.25)</p>
</messageContent>
```

Comment: Step 1: Research if this question is already answered. ;)

Comment: nothing much still researching

Comment: You should do that before you ask here and include the result into your question in case you can't solve it on your own. I vote to close this question now since I found the answer within one minute, I guess you will hit it too. :)

Comment: `Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("</?[^>]+>");
Matcher match = tags.matcher (yourContent); // here you specify the string you want to modify (HTML)
String result = match.replaceAll("");`

Comment: @Dinesh: He didn't do anything, you can still edit your question.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string
My favorite solution: android.text.Html.fromHtml(string_in_html).toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function this way,

```
public String removeTags(String in)
    {
        int index=0;
        int index2=0;
        while(index!=-1)
        {
            index = in.indexOf("<");
            index2 = in.indexOf(">", index);
            if(index!=-1 && index2!=-1)
            {
                in = in.substring(0, index).concat(in.substring(index2+1, in.length()));
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
```

I tried to do that with the function `replaceAll()` using regular experssion, but never had a good way.