# Reading webpages on Android Phone without html tags

Tags: android, html

I want to read webpages on Android phone and have a code sample below. But with this code I get all items on the webpage. But I just want to get articles on the webpage. I dont want to get them with Html tags. How can I receive only articles on the web page?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the websites your are querying for articles contain text-only content (perhaps in the form of an RSS feed), the best you can do is to get the full HTML and text and then attempt to strip out the HTML tags. This is pretty unreliable as there are few full proof solutions to parsing HTML inside a string.

Try this: [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)