# Only text without html and css tags

Tags: android, html, css

I have an email body and it has html,css tags and I am trying to retrieve only the body text in Android.

I used;

```
String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(body);
```

and that gave me the text with css tags. What should I do for retrieve only the text? 
Result is holding in a String

Normally (when I first receive body );

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style><!--
    .hmmessage P
    {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px
    }
    body.hmmessage
    {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family:Tahoma
    }
    --></style></head>
    <body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>
    TEXTONE<div>TEXTTWO</div>                     </div></body>
    </html>
```

After String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(body);

```
<!-- .hmmessage P { margin:0px; padding:0px } body.hmmessage { font-size: 10pt; font-family:Tahoma } -->

TEXTONE
TEXTTWO
```

I just want to receive TEXTONE and TEXTTWO

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing android development in Java - if you're not, yell at me. IF you are, you might take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: Look especially at the second highest voted answer.

Comment: I am already separate the text and html tags. But I am looking a solution for sepaarate the text from css tags