# Removing HTML Tags from a String

Tags: android, html, parsing

I have a HTML string:

```
<span class=thisword>anh</span><br />
-grand frère</span><br />
-cousin (fils d'un grand frère ou d'une grande soeur du père ou de la mère)</span><br />
-(nom générique désignant un homme encore jeune)</span><br />
```

I want to get the strings in it.
I have done the following:

```
Elements ed=docu.getElementsByTag("span");
for(Element e: ed)
{
    System.out.println(removeHTML(e.toString()));
    // removeHTML is method remove tags in HTML receive
}
```

It only displays the string

```
anh
```

I want it to display

```
anh -grand frère -cousin (fils d'un grand frère ou d'une grande soeur du père ou de la mère) -(nom générique désignant un homme encore jeune)
```

but I haven't had any success. Can you help me?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of ["Removing HTML from a Java String."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML isn't valid... you can't expect much anything from that.

Your program is probably outputting four strings, one with text, the other three empty. Your HTML is being interpreted like this (at least to most browsers):

```
<span class=thisword>anh</span><br />
-grand frère<span></span><br />
-cousin (fils d'un grand frère ou d'une grande soeur du père ou de la mère)<span></span><br />
-(nom générique désignant un homme encore jeune)<span></span><br />
```

You're not opening all these other spans that you're supposedly closing. You need to start a new span before each line of text if you want it all to be included:

```
<span class=thisword>anh</span><br />
<span>-grand frère</span><br />
<span>-cousin (fils d'un grand frère ou d'une grande soeur du père ou de la mère)</span><br />
<span>-(nom générique désignant un homme encore jeune)</span><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Html structure does not seem to be correct. You have one opening span and four closing spans. This could be one reason.

Answer (score 0):

The correct HTML should be :

```
<span class="thisword">anh</span><br />
<span>-grand frère</span><br />
<span>-cousin (fils d'un grand frère ou d'une grande soeur du père ou de la mère)</span><br />
<span>-(nom générique désignant un homme encore jeune)</span><br />
```

You should note these:

- Classes should be given in quotes.
- Each block should be closed and opened within the respective `<p>` or `<div>`. `<span>` should have a matching `</span>` within them.
- Spans should not overlap each other.

Comment: Ideally, when you are parsing Spans.  you aren't supposed to.

Comment: But HTML string that I get from Internet haven't as you write.

Comment: @treehh  can you provide the elaborate html code you are obtaining from the internet(a website source i presume)..  There is another way to obtain the text from HTML than reading it span by span.