# Using Java how do I strip the html from a pop3 email when reading it using javamail?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-mail, pop3, strip-tags

I need to let users submit an email to an address which will be used to populate entities in my database. My program will periodically check the inbox for new mail and when it finds a new mail item, I need to use the subject, from, sent date, attachments and body to populate DB entities. I have been able to get all of the fields, but I am having trouble with the body when it contains html. I just need to store the text of the email. I would like to strip out all tags, signatures, etc. from the body. Is there a better way to do this other than regex?

Here is the function I am using to get the body text. My problem lies when the mimetype hits the "multipart/*" case in the last part of the function. The function returns the html message. What can I do to strip the tags in that section other than regex?

```
    /**
 * Return the primary text content of the message.
 */
private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String s = (String)p.getContent();
        textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
        return s;
    }

    if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
        // prefer html text over plain text
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        String text = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                if (text == null){
                    text = getText(bp);
                }
                continue;
            } 
            else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                String s = getText(bp);
                if (s != null){
                    return s;
                }
            } 
            else {
                return getText(bp);
            }
        }
        return text;
    } 
    else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            if (s != null)
                return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

I've been trying the following, but it is resulting in the spanish á problem I have commented about below.

```
 else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
            String retText = doc.text();
            retText.replaceAll("[0%d0%a]", "<br />");
            if (retText != null)
                return retText;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried [\r\n] and [\n] as my regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: If I may ask, what is the reason for wanting to remove the html tags?  Why not just escape the html string and store as is?

Comment: I need to remove the tags because I need to store just the text of the email for use in other pages of the application where the html formatting will get in the way and a simple text string is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to traverse the HTML code and extract just the text that you want.

Take a look:

- http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document
- http://jsoup.org/apidocs
- http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html

Comment: I kind of got this working, but for some reason when I print the body text to the command line, all of the line breaks show as a spanish á. Is this just an issue with printing to the command line? I am also trying to use regex to simply replace the á with a <br /> tag which is acceptable for my solution, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try to send the output to a file to see what happens?

Comment: OK, outputting to a file gets rid of the spanish á. However, it just leaves a space in it's place. It's a start and I may be able to work with that, although a <br /> instead of a space would be preferred.

Comment: <br/> is a tag and when you take only the text, <br/> will be removed. I think that during the traversal, you can detected <br/> tags and use an "\n" in its place during the text extraction, i.e., if current tag == <br/>, return "\n".

Comment: I'm not actually traversing the nodes. I am using the Jsoup.parse() function to get the Document object and then calling doc.text() to essentially strip the html. Perhaps I can use the java String replaceAll() method on the Document prior to getting the text?