# Format text to remove html tags

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I'm using LastFM API to get artists info. When I call their `artist.getInfo` method, I get a Artist object. However, the wiki summary text is formatted with html like this:

```
Arch Enemy is a Swedish <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/melodic%20death%20metal" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">melodic death metal</a> band from Halmstad, Sweden, formed in 1996. Founded by <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Carcass" class="bbcode_artist">Carcass</a> guitarist <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Michael+Amott" class="bbcode_artist">Michael Amott</a> along with <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Johan+Liiva" class="bbcode_artist">Johan Liiva</a>, both originally from the influential death metal band <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Carnage" class="bbcode_artist">Carnage</a>. The band has released seven studio albums, a live album (Burning Japan Live 1999), two DVDs and three EPs. The band was originally fronted by Johan Liiva, who was replaced by <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Angela+Gossow" class="bbcode_artist">Angela Gossow</a> as lead vocalist in 2000
```

I want to get plain text (html-less) from this text. I've tried removing them manually with substrings, but I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: We have used Jericho HTML Parse in the past for this: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Someone here also asked a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Comment: Yes. [This seems fine one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/940096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class Html in Android. The simplest way to use this class, you can see method fromHtml(...), it returns Spannable which can be easily converted to plain text.

So the example would be next:

```
String htmlString = "<div>text</div><a href=\"someref\">link</a>";
String plainText = Html.fromHtml(htmlString).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It has very great features of extracting plain text from `HTML`.

All you have to do is:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/some-location/index.html");
   // NOTE: Use ArticleExtractor unless DefaultExtractor gives better results for you
   String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

This is text extraction from URL. But is it features that you can pass a `String` as `HTML`. I've been using it and it works the best of all I've tried.