# Android rss feed parsing

Tags: android, rss

I am new to android,In my application i have to parse the data and i need to display in screen.But in one particular tag data i can't able to parse why because some special character also coming inside that tag.Here below i display my code.

My parser function:

```
  protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
//      context = params[0];
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();     
        test = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new java.net.URL("input URL_confidential").openConnection().getInputStream());
            //Document document = builder.parse(new URL("http://www.gamestar.de/rss/gamestar.rss").openConnection().getInputStream());
            Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList docItems = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
            Node nodeItem;
            for(int i = 0;i<docItems.getLength();i++)
            {
                nodeItem = docItems.item(i);
                if(nodeItem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    NodeList element = nodeItem.getChildNodes();                    
                    Element entry = (Element) docItems.item(i);
                    name=(element.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());




//                 System.out.println("description = "+element.item(2).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().replaceAll("&lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt;"," "));
                    System.out.println("Description"+Jsoup.clean(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(element.item(2).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()), new Whitelist()));             


                    items.add(name);


                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>my application</title>
<link>http:// some link</link>
<atom:link href="http:// XXXXXXXX" rel="self"></atom:link>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 20 Dec 2012</lastBuildDate>
<item>
<title>lllegal settlements</title>
<link>http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</link>
<description> &lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt;
India was joined by all members of the 15-nation UN Security Council except the US to condemn Israelâ€™s announcement of new construction activity in Palestinian territories and demand immediate dismantling of the â€œillegalâ€ settlements.
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
UN Secretary General Ban Ki-moon also expressed his deep concern by the heightened settlement activity in West Bank, saying the move by Israel â€œgravely threatens efforts to establish a viable Palestinian state.â€
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
</description>
</item>
</channel>
```

Output:

```
 lllegal settlements  ----> title tag text

     India was joined by all members of the 15-nation UN Security Council except the US to condemn Israel announcement of new construction activity in Palestinian territories and demand immediate dismantling of the illegal settlements. -----> description tag text

     UN Secretary General Ban Ki-moon also expressed his deep concern by the heightened settlement activity in West Bank, saying the move by Israel gravely threatens efforts to establish a viable Palestinian state.    ----> description tag text.
```

Comment: <description> &lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt;
An independent inquiry into the September 11 attack on the US Consulate in Benghazi that killed the US ambassador to Libya and three other Americans has found that systematic failures at the State Department led to â€œgrosslyâ€ inadequate security at the mission.
&lt;/p&gt;</description>

Answer (score 4):

Your *text node* contains both escaped HTML entities (`&gt;` is `>`, *greater then*) and garbage characters (*â€œgrosslyâ€*). You should first adjust the encoding according to your input source, then you can *unescape* the HTML with [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`StringUtils.escapeHtml4(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29).

This method (hopefully) returns an XML which you can query (for example with XPath) to extract the wanted text node, or you can give the whole string to [JSOUP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/315306) or to [the Android `Html` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6385950/315306)

```
// JSOUP, "html" is the unescaped string. Returns a string
Jsoup.parse(html).text();

// Android
android.text.Html.fromHtml(instruction).toString()
```

Test program (JSOUP and Commons-Lang required)

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

public class EmbeddedHTML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String src = "<description> &lt;div&gt;&lt;p&gt; An independent" +
                " inquiry into the September 11 attack on the US Consulate" +
                " in Benghazi that killed the US ambassador to Libya and" +
                " three other Americans has found that systematic failures" +
                " at the State Department led to â€œgrosslyâ€ inadequate" +
                " security at the mission. &lt;/p&gt;</description>";
        String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(src);
        System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(unescaped, new Whitelist()));
    }

}
```

Comment: By using this "element.item(2).getFirstChild().getNodeValue():"

Comment: i can able to go corresponding node,but i cant get the value in that

Comment: One more thing i don't have the control to change the input (i.e) Xml file

Comment: You don't have to change anything. I can't understand why you think you got the right node if you are not able to see its content...

Comment: why because in that tag some special character are coming..,that the issue raffaele.

Comment: Inside that tag first some special characters are coming,After that the actual data appending.so i can't take the actual data.Please tell some logic to remove the special character.sorry for my poor english

Comment: @neha88 I wrote a test program and it seems to work. If it's not what you need, maybe you should first improve your communication skills...

Comment: hi Reffaele..I can't import this header file "import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;"any jar i need to use for this

Comment: I have JSoup..,but i need Apache commons-Lang

Comment: [And you can't download it yourself](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi)?

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME??? CLICK THE [LINK](http://it.apache.contactlab.it//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.1-bin.tar.gz)!!!

Comment: thanks reffaele..Now i am getting Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: @neha88 if you never used a Java library before, I don't think I can help you in comments. Just read the documentation of your IDE

Comment: Just i added the jar in my project and imported in my class file,but it showing error like.."java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils."

Comment: I will explain clearly..I am hitting the URL. The Url return the response in XML format.In that i have one tag called Description.The problem is i cant extract the data in description tag.

Comment: @neha88 This program is straightforward. Update your question and paste both input source and desired output. Based on your requirements, the program works

Comment: @neha88 I can't do your homework for you. If you need to extract `<title>` and `<description>` separately, just do it. Use the DOM api, or something like XPath to extract them. Then you can use the title as-is, and can feed the `<description>` content to the code I posted above. It's not that *the logic doesn't work*, is that I answered your question

Comment: As u said feed the <description> content to the code I posted above code ..My problem is that i didnt get that <description> content from my rss feed.SO after getting this only i can use it..But i cant get that content from my rss feed.I have posted the parser section in my question..

Comment: This is getting boring. If you don't know how to program altogether, log out of StackOverflow and go buy a programming book. You asked how to process the *description* content - and, ok, that's a reasonable question. Now you state you don't know how to get to `<descritpion>`, and what do you expect? It's an XML file, just look on the internet how you can extract parts with the DOM interface. The "parser" you posted doesn't even contain the word *description* , so I guess you simply copied it without even understanding what it does. Just google for "Java XML processing"

Comment: Thanks for your advise.As i said in my question  i am beginner to this android..I googled for extracting data(parsing) and then i parsed some urls.But in my above case something it contains different format of data(RSS feed),so i faced the problem...From beginning i am saying i cant able to get the Description tag  value..But i think now only u understand my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with simply replacing the offending characters?

```
string = string.replaceAll("&lt;", "");
string = string.replaceAll("div&gt;", "");
string = string.replaceAll("p&gt;", "");
```

Comment: Thanks Aelexe. Even i cant able to get the data..I tried with above my code it not displaying anything.I have the problem to extract the data.Once if i extract i can do this replaceall() method.

Answer (score 0):

Run the node value with Html.fromHTML() two or three times and it wil be fine.

EXPLANATION: The built-in Html.fromHTML() method will convert wild and broken HTML into usable content. Pseudo code here:

```
sHTML = node.getNodeValue()
sHTML = Html.fromHTML(sHTML)
sHTML = Html.fromHTML(sHTML)
sHTML = Html.fromHTML(sHTML)
```

By the the third or fourth time unreadable content will become readable again. You can display it in a textview or loaddata with a webview.

Comment: You have a nice name.

Comment: And a nice face, too ;)