# How can I search content in HTML and not the tags

Tags: android, html, ios, core-data, windows-phone

I have a database of content of which the majority are HTML pages which are then used for display purposes in an app.

We are looking to build out a search feature but I have some concerns over false positives appearing due to the results including HTML code.

E.g searching for "title" will return any content pages which have a title html tag

We are currently using NSPredicates to perform the query on a Core Data database.

Are there any easy/efficient ways to prevent these results being returned?

I have the same problem on Windows and Android as well!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 1):

One idea for iOS is to actually store a separate a text version apart from the HTML version. You could then use very simple (even if not very efficient) predicates lie

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
```

A more performant way would be to strip out the words and store them in lowercase in an indexed attribute of another entity.

In both cases, the parsing should be done beforehand via one of the available libraries (see e.g. link in the comment).