# Removing all html markup

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I have a string that holds a complete XML get request.

In the request, there is a lot of HTML and some custom commands which I would like to remove.

The only way of doing so I know is by using [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

For example [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string).

Now, because the website the request came from also features custom commands, I was not able to completely remove all code.

For example here is a string I would like to '*clean*':

```
\u0027s normal text here\u003c/b\u003e http://a_random_link_here.com\r\n\r\nSome more text here
```

As you can see, the *custom commands* all have backslashes in front of them.

How would I go about removing these commands with Java?

If I use regex, how can I program it such that it only removes the command, not anything after the command?
(because if I softcode: I don't know the size of the command beforehand and I don't want to hardcode all the commands).

Comment: Can you assume a white space after the command? Does it always start with `\u`? What would you like the "cleaned" string to look like (exactly)?

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but unfortunately, there are also (java like) commands. For example at the end of the example string: `\r\n\r\nSome more text here`

Comment: Those are just CRLF characters. Do you want to strip those too, or keep them?

Comment: @Floris: I want to remove those too. If we seperate between CRLF and the other commands I think I can assume a white space after commands.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `http://` link?

Comment: @Floris: Yes. I only want to remove the styling markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://regex101.com/r/gJ2yN2

The regex `(\\.\d{3,}.*?\s|(\\r|\\n)+)` works to remove the things you were pointing out.

Result (replacing the match with a  single space):

```
normal text here http://a_random_link_here.com Some more text here
```

If this was not the result you were looking for, please edit your question with the expected result.

**EDIT** regex explained:

```
()  - match everything inside the parentheses (later, the "match" gets replaced with "space")
\\  - an 'escaped' backslash (i.e. an actual backslash; the first one "protects" the second
      so it is not interpreted as a special character
.   - any character (I saw 'u', but there might be others
\d  - a digit
{3,} - "at least three"
.*? - any characters, "lazy" (stop as soon as possible)
\s  - until you hit a white space
|   - or
()  - one of these things
\\r - backslash - r (again, with escaped '\')
\\n - backslash - n
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! If you feel like it, would you mind explaining what you did with this regex expression? I don't quite get the used syntax.

Comment: Let me know if the explanation clears it up for you.

Comment: My question was originally tagged `java`. Today I tried converting your answer into the Java version of it (//// instead of //) but I didn't success with the `\d`, do you know the correct, full Java syntax for this regex string?

Answer (score 0):

The "custom commands" you're showing us appear to be standard character escapes. \r is carriage return, ASCII 13 (decimal). \n is new line, ASCII 10 (decimal). \uxxxx is generally an escape for the Unicode character with that hex value -- for example, \u0027 is ASCII character 39, the apostrophe character ('). You don't want to discard these; they're part of the text content you're trying to retrieve.

So the best answer is to make sure you know which escapes to accept in this dataset and then either find or write code which does a quick linear scan through the code looking for \ and, when found, using the next character to determine which kind of escape it is (and how many subsequent characters belong to that kind of escape), replace the escape sequence with the single character it represents, and continue until you reach the end of the string/buffer/file/whatever.