# regex - custom command + capital letter right after

Tags: java, regex, string

I am processing a XML get request that features custom commands from the website the request comes from.

Now I'm trying to remove the custom commands from the request.

An example of one of the strings I am trying to clean:

```
\u003cb\u003eText here\u003c/b\u003e \u003c/u\u003e\u003c/b\u003e \r\n\r\n
```

Now the output I'd like to get after cleaning is:

```
Text here
```

Now the current regex I have (from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819988/removing-all-html-markup)) is this:

```
String myRegex = "(\\\\.\\d{3,}.*?\\s|\\\\r|\\\\n)";
```

But the problem is, that it also removes `Text` because it comes directly after `\u003e`

How can I change the regex such that it doesn't delete `Text`?

- We can assume a command starts with `\`
- We can assume a command stops with a lower case letter : \u003 **e**
- We can assume that if there is a capital letter right after a command, that it is not part of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex string is not working because it is looking for a space `\\s` to complete the string, that is found after the *"Text"* word.

I removed it and managed to set an interval `[a-z]` instead of any character `.`, according to your specifications: only lowercase letters are allowed in commands.

This regex will do the trick. I am assuming that only capital letters or spaces are interrupting the command, since there is no way to know if a lowercase letter is part of a word or not.

```
String myRegex = "(\\\\.\\d{3,}[a-z]*?|\\\\r|\\\\n)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer**

I took the long way and softcoded the general command syntax and then hardcoded some command leftovers like `b`, `\b`, `u`, `\u`, `i` and `\i`:

```
public static String regexReplace(String toReplace)
{
    String regex    = "(\\\\[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-z]|\\\\r|\\\\n)";
    String regextwo = "(\\s[b]\\s|\\s\\/[b]\\s|\\s[u]\\s|\\s\\/[u]\\s|\\s[i]\\s|\\s\\/[i]\\s)";
    return toReplace.replaceAll(regex, " ").replaceAll(regextwo, "");
}
```