# Read online document in java

Tags: java

I am using

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt"); 
Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
```

to read my document. But when I am trying to output the string then I am getting some unnecessary tags. My requirements is to be able to read the document as it is(i.e. without any unnecessary tags.)

Below is the peice of code I have written:

```
URL url = new URL("Link");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
String[] wordArray;
int wordCount;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(str);
wordArray = str.split("\\s+");
wordCount = wordArray.length;
System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);
}

in.close();
```

Below is the output I am getting. I donot want any unneccessary tags which you can see in the below output. I just want the actual text which you can see between tags. Unnecessary tags mean

,  etc. which you see in the below output snippet. I just want texts like 'UNITED STATES SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE' etc. in my string.

```
Word count is = 1
<P STYLE="font: 10pt/normal Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center"></P>
Word count is = 12

Word count is = 1
<P STYLE="font: 10pt/normal Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center"><B>UNITED STATES SECURITIES AND EXCHANGE
Word count is = 16
COMMISSION</B></P>
Word count is = 1

Word count is = 1
<P STYLE="font: 10pt/normal Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center"><B>Washington, D.C. 20549</B></P>
Word count is = 14

Word count is = 1
<P STYLE="font: 10pt/normal Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center"><B>&nbsp;</B></P>
Word count is = 12
```

Comment: Which unnecessary tags are you getting?

Comment: Define "unnecessary tags"...

Comment: what is the output
write 1st 5 lines

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 5):

What you are getting back is the HTML source code.  If you are interested in just the contents of the body tag for example, you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to extract it AND remove all the tags within the body too.

Answer (score 2):

jsoup does stuff like this:

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    String url = "http://www.google.com"
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if(doc==null)
        return;

    //start browsing
    // something like
    for(Element p : doc.getElementsByTag("p")){
        System.out.println(p.text());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jsoup Library for this job [ http://www.jsoup.org ]. See the code below, I have used the URL you mentioned in your question and have extracted the text.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String url = "http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTag("body").html());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```