# SKipping image while converting html text to string android

Tags: android, html

Iam converting some Html text from a webpage into a String by doing the following

```
 mydescription =Html.fromHtml(data.getBody()).toString();
```

This is what `data.getBody()` returns:-

```
<div><p>​It's great to have great dynamic companies to work with, and NXP is no exception.</p><p><img alt="This is an image of NXP Logo" src="https://anprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/b75ef288-0381-45c4-a4cd-809097370bec/untitled.png" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br></p><div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https&#58;//www.youtube.com/embed/I6191gXXGog" frameborder="0"></iframe>&#160;</div><p>​<br></p></div>
```

But within that html text there is a image source as well. When I do the above I get a square image with obj written inside it instead of the image.

This is `myDescription`

￼

I just want to get the text and not the image.

How do i just get the text and not the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String htmlString  = "<div><p>​It's great to have great dynamic companies to work with, and NXP is no exception.</p><p><img alt=\"This is an image of NXP Logo\" src=\"https://anprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/b75ef288-0381-45c4-a4cd-809097370bec/untitled.png\" style=\"margin&#58;5px;\" /><br></p><div><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https&#58;//www.youtube.com/embed/I6191gXXGog\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>&#160;</div><p>​<br></p></div>";
String first = htmlString.substring(0,htmlString.indexOf("<img"));
String second = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("/>",htmlString.indexOf("<img"))+2,htmlString.length());
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(first+second));
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise using libraries, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) when working with HTML (with soup you will be able to get only text by calling `Jsoup.parse(html).text()`)

*Haven't tried it myself*

```
private static final Pattern REMOVE_TAGS = Pattern.compile("<img>(\\S+)</img>");

public static String removeTags(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return string;
    }

    Matcher m = REMOVE_TAGS.matcher(string);
    return m.replaceAll("");
}
```

If you want to strip down all the HTML code, then you can use:

```
replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")
```

---

For your second question (from Source 2):

```
    // the pattern we want to search for
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<p>(\\S+)</p>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

    // if we find a match, get the group 
    if (m.find())
    {
      // get the matching group
      String codeGroup = m.group(1);

      // print the group
      System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup);
    }
```

Source: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095615/1276374), [2](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-extract-html-tag-string-regex-pattern-matcher-group) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240630/1276374)

Comment: is there any way I can get just the text between the first pair of <p></p> tags?

Comment: @user3713706 answered this question too (added to the original answer)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
String clippedBody = htmlString.replaceAll("<img[^>]*?>.*?/[^>]*?>", "");
```

Comment: I get a square image with OBJ written inside it. I added it after the myDescription line