# How can I extract only the text (stripping out timecodes) from SubRip .srt files?

Tags: java, netbeans, extract, subtitle, srt

I'd like to use text only from a subtitle for further processing.

So, opening a srt file would load this

```
1
00:00:10,500 --> 00:00:13,000
Elephant's Dream

2
00:00:15,000 --> 00:00:18,000
At the left we can see...
```

Then, after stripping/extracting, the result would be

```
Elephant's Dream
At the left we can see...
```

I want to strip out all the numbering and timecode, so the output would consist only of plain text in the exact same order as the original subtitle, and store the result in a variable for further processing.

```
public void open_file()
{
    JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
    filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int i  = filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (i == filechooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
        return;
    File OpenFile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (OpenFile  == null || OpenFile.getName().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "choose file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(BukaFile));
        StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String Row;
        while ((Row = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) stringbuffer.append(Row+"\n");
        textArea.setText(stringbuffer.toString());
        String SubText = textArea.getText();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found" + ex);
    } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IO Error"+ ex);
            }
}
```

I've made a method (as above) to open and load an existing srt file and put it into a String (named SubText above) variable.

To extract those texts, all I know is that I have to use either numberings, timecodes, and blank space for start point and end point, but I have no idea on how to code for detecting those numberings and timecodes in the text.

How should I accomplish this in java? I'm using Netbeans, by the way.

Comment: You could maybe skip the first two lines then read one line, skip 3 lines, read one line, skip 3 lines etc.

Comment: well, the problem is that, some text are sometimes more than one line, so i can't just "skip 3 line" over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is simple, each subtitle is separated by a blank line so all you do is skip the first 2 lines then read everything until you get to a blank line.

So replace you while loop with something like this...

```
    while (...) {
        String lineNumber = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String time = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String text;
        while (!(text = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals(""))
            stringBuffer.append(text).append("\n");
    }
```

Be sure to add your own end of file check.

Comment: my while loop in there is used for write down untouched srt in a textarea, with while loop to read and append texts until the end of file (as condition). when i tried to implement your while loop so that my while loop write down stripped srt, textarea only filled with blank line. do i have to change my while condition?

Comment: Oops! Got logic wrong way round, should have been !equals(""). I've   now corrected.

Comment: thanks a lot sir :) it worked! BTW, because of my while loop condition, i only need one bufferedreader skip. and, do you have any idea how can i remove html tags in srt file? (such as <i> or <u>)

Comment: already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string

Comment: i am using Jsoup lib and i've used parse method on a string, but it doesn't do anything. am i using wrong method to strip html tags?

Comment: my bad, i am using the wrong method. using clean method and all those tags are gone, but also all the \n (blank line). how can i avoid this?

Comment: Clean the line first then add a return after.

Comment: funny how i've been working on this all night just to no avail, but simple advice from you enlighten me so easily.. once again, THANK YOU SIR :)