# count the number of words using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to count the number of words from my html page
and using hashmap i want to print the words and the occurences of the word from the html page

Java code

```
public class CountWords {

    public void readFile() {

        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Test.html"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }

        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());

        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(entries.get(entries.size() - i - 1).getKey()
                    + " " + entries.get(entries.size() - i - 1).getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

the output i m getting is the raw data with the html code also and i want to print only the text inside the page which i m seeing not the html code

Comment: Use a html parser to parse the page and count the result.

Comment: all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline 1
in: 1
removed 1
g};a.k.W=function(b,c,d){if(b){var 1
if("cad=h"==b)return 1
valign="top"><td 1
Google</a><a 1  @GautamSavaliya

Comment: Hi User html parser and get all text from html and count no of words. U can see jsoup parser

Answer (score 0):

You could try the OWASP HTML Sanitization library https://owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project. I've used it previously in sanitizing user submitted posts, but it should achieve what you require. As it is a library that allows/restricts specific tags within a piece of HTML you can tell it to deny all HTML tags and just extract the content within them.

You're code would be something like 
    `PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().toFactory();
    String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(htmlContent);`

I've found it to be much less error prone than trying any kind of Regular Expression.

You'll probably need both the guava.jar and owasp-java-html-sanitizer.jar from http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/lib/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the HTML tags. Here is an example: [Remove HTML tags from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Btw. why your output is so complicated?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s %d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```