# How to remove Html tags from Blob in Jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, blob

I am having `DocumentVariable` (Struts Bean variable with blob data) which contains data along with Html tags. How to remove html tags and display only text.

```
<s:label name="documentDAO.documentAllContent" />

<p>/*<br /> &nbsp;* This is a JavaScript Scratchpad.<br /> &nbsp;*<br /> &nbsp;* Enter some JavaScript, then Right Click or choose from the Execute Menu:<br /> &nbsp;* 1. Run to evaluate the selected text (Ctrl+R),<br /> &nbsp;* 2. Inspect to bring up an Object Inspector on the result (Ctrl+I), or,<br /> &nbsp;* 3. Display to insert the result in a comment after the selection. (Ctrl+L)<br /> &nbsp;*/</p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<s:label>` tag? Use `<s:property>` - it escapes html by default.

Comment: I am using data from CKEditor, Even if i am using <s:property> i am getting data with tags. <p>sfhsdfhsdf</p> <p>sfdhsfdhsfdhsfdhsdfh</p> <p>hgdf</p>

Comment: Do you want to escape them or not? If not then set `escapeHtml` attribute to false.

Comment: i want to remove html tags and Display plain text on jsp

Comment: Without formatting? Why do you use ckeditor then?

Comment: I have added Document into DB and now want to View Document, When i am fetching data from DB getting Blob which contains Html tags as well. I just want to view data in lable or textarea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68483/discussion-between-code-hungry-and-aleksandr-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear, though probably worthing an explanation covering all cases.

You use CKEditor to create an HTML, then save it into a `BLOB` field (that should be used for binary data, what you want here is a `CLOB`, but that's another story).

Then you retrieve your content, and at this point you may have three different desired results:

1. **HTML** (eg. `<b>foo</b>` rendered as **`foo`**):

   ```xml
   <s:property value="yourVar" escapeHtml="false" />
   ```
2. **Plain text** (eg. `<b>foo</b>` rendered as `<b>foo</b>`)

   ```xml
   <s:property value="yourVar" />
   ```
3. **Plain/Text without HTML tags** (eg. `<b>foo</b>` rendered as `foo`): for this you need to use an HTML parser in your action class (eg. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149645/1654265))

   ```java
   private byte[] yourVar; 

   public String getYourVar() {
       return Jsoup.parse(new String(yourVar, "UTF-8")).text();
   }
   ```

   ```xml
   <s:property value="yourVar" />
   ```