# Php opposite of Striptags

Tags: php, html, function, tags

Is it possible to remove everything but the tags from a string?

```
E.g.: "<br>Hello World!</br>" --> "<br></br>"
```

Is there a built-in function for that?

Comment: Yes it is possible; question: answered ✓

Comment: @Rizier123 100 points to you!

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: @GabrielVilella Oh you want to do it. Have you tried something on your own?

Comment: Ok let make this question more clear. Is there a bult-in function for that?

Comment: @GabrielVilella Well that's another question and no there is no 1 build-in function to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML tags from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Yes it is.

```
preg_match_all('/<*?>(.*?)<\/*?>/', $html, $result);
echo implode("", $result);
```